# How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, synchronous

I have a `public async Task Foo()` method that I want to call from a synchronous method. So far all I have seen from MSDN documentation is calling `async` methods via `async` methods, but my whole program is not built with `async` methods.

Is this even possible?

Here's one example of calling these methods from an asynchronous method:
[Walkthrough: Accessing the Web by Using Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh300224(v=vs.110))

Now I'm looking into calling these `async` methods from synchronous methods.

Comment: I ran into this as well.  Overriding a RoleProvider you cannot change the method signature of the GetRolesForUser method so you can not make the method async and so cannot use await to call out to api asyncronously.  My temporary solution was to add synchronous methods to my generic HttpClient class but would like to know if this is possible (and what the implications might be).

Comment: Because your `async void Foo()` method does not return a `Task` it means a caller cannot know when it completes, it must return `Task` instead.

Comment: Linking a [related q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53508160/1768303) on how to do this on a UI thread.

Comment: I've used this method and seems to do the job: MyMethodAsync.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); Before that, you might want to check the following article that ends up boiling down to deadlocks and threadpool starvation:
https://medium.com/rubrikkgroup/understanding-async-avoiding-deadlocks-e41f8f2c6f5d

Comment: @Timothy Lee Russell I don't think GetRolesForUser() should do much. Especially not call time consuming async methods.

Comment: @Dai I edited the question and corrected this (most likely unintentional) mistake.

Answer (score 1092, accepted):

Asynchronous programming does "grow" through the code base. It has been [compared to a zombie virus](https://web.archive.org/web/20190126143814/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2011/04/15/async-ctp-refresh-design-changes/). The best solution is to allow it to grow, but sometimes that's not possible.

I have written a few types in my [Nito.AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) library for dealing with a partially-asynchronous code base. There's no solution that works in every situation, though.

**Solution A**

If you have a simple asynchronous method that doesn't need to synchronize back to its context, then you can use `Task.WaitAndUnwrapException`:

```
var task = MyAsyncMethod();
var result = task.WaitAndUnwrapException();
```

You do *not* want to use `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result` because they wrap exceptions in `AggregateException`.

This solution is only appropriate if `MyAsyncMethod` does not synchronize back to its context. In other words, every `await` in `MyAsyncMethod` should end with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. This means it can't update any UI elements or access the ASP.NET request context.

**Solution B**

If `MyAsyncMethod` does need to synchronize back to its context, then you may be able to use `AsyncContext.RunTask` to provide a nested context:

```
var result = AsyncContext.RunTask(MyAsyncMethod).Result;
```

---

*Update 4/14/2014: In more recent versions of the library the API is as follows:

```
var result = AsyncContext.Run(MyAsyncMethod);
```

---

(It's OK to use `Task.Result` in this example because `RunTask` will propagate `Task` exceptions).

The reason you may need `AsyncContext.RunTask` instead of `Task.WaitAndUnwrapException` is because of a rather subtle deadlock possibility that happens on WinForms/WPF/SL/ASP.NET:

1. A synchronous method calls an async method, obtaining a `Task`.
2. The synchronous method does a blocking wait on the `Task`.
3. The `async` method uses `await` without `ConfigureAwait`.
4. The `Task` cannot complete in this situation because it only completes when the `async` method is finished; the `async` method cannot complete because it is attempting to schedule its continuation to the `SynchronizationContext`, and WinForms/WPF/SL/ASP.NET will not allow the continuation to run because the synchronous method is already running in that context.

This is one reason why it's a good idea to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` within every `async` method as much as possible.

**Solution C**

`AsyncContext.RunTask` won't work in every scenario. For example, if the `async` method awaits something that requires a UI event to complete, then you'll deadlock even with the nested context. In that case, you could start the `async` method on the thread pool:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => await MyAsyncMethod());
var result = task.WaitAndUnwrapException();
```

However, this solution requires a `MyAsyncMethod` that will work in the thread pool context. So it can't update UI elements or access the ASP.NET request context. And in that case, you may as well add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to its `await` statements, and use solution A.

**Update:** 2015 MSDN article '[Async Programming - Brownfield Async Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development)' by Stephen Cleary.

Comment: Solution A seems like what I want, but it looks like task.WaitAndUnwrapException() didn't make it into the .Net 4.5 RC; it only has task.Wait(). Any idea how to do this with the new version? Or is this a custom extension method you wrote?

Comment: `WaitAndUnwrapException` is my own method from my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/). The official .NET libs don't provide much help for mixing sync and async code (and in general, you shouldn't do it!). I'm waiting for .NET 4.5 RTW and a new non-XP laptop before updating AsyncEx to run on 4.5 (I cannot currently develop for 4.5 because I'm stuck on XP for a few more weeks).

Comment: I have tried to use Nito.AsyncEx, but the `Task` Method gives me an ambiguity error... (It doesn't have RunkTask)
How do I solve it?

Comment: `AsyncContext` now has a `Run` method that takes a lambda expression, so you should use `var result = AsyncContext.Run(() => MyAsyncMethod());`

Comment: I got your library off Nuget, but it doesn't actually seem to have a `RunTask` method. Closest thing I could find was `Run`, but that doesn't have a `Result` property.

Comment: @Asad: Yes, more than 2 years later the API has changed. [You can now simply say `var result = AsyncContext.Run(MyAsyncMethod);`](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext)

Comment: Yes, I found that page after some digging around. Should have done more research before commenting. I've updated the answer to reflect the new API just in case someone else is lazy.

Comment: @StephenCleary, I have a synchronous method calling async with `.Result`. It works fine when called via wcf or REST. But it fails when invoked via NUnit. How is this possible, if you could provide your comments. Thanks

Comment: @BabuJames: It could be due to the fact that [async method continuations use the `ExecuteSynchronously` flag](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html); I explore this more on my blog.

Comment: @StephenCleary
Just wondering: what about:

`T UnAsync<T>(Task<T> task)`
`{`
`    while (!task.IsCompleted)`
`    {`
`        Thread.Yield();`
`    }`

`    return task.Result;`
`}`

used like this:

`var result = UnAsync(MyAsyncMethod())`
?

Comment: @sonatique: That can easily hit 100% CPU with the busy-waiting loop. Also `Result` will wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`.

Comment: @StephenCleary: thanks a lot for your reply. Yes indeed, it should be used only where hitting 100% CPU is not an issue, or when one know that the operation won't last too long. Anyway when we have to do such async to sync we're already a little bit in a gray zone, right? My goal was to avoid creating a new task or thread, and to absolutely avoid .Wait/.Result since the function we're in may look "sync" but might have been called with an await somewhere up in the call stack...
Regarding exceptions: yes indeed, my actual implementation use a try.catch and your PrepareForRethrow ;-)

Comment: By the way, since I am using Thread.Yield() I assume that we'll hit 100% CPU only when there is noting else to do, such that we won't starve other threads; do you think am I correct?

Comment: @sonatique: No, you'll always hit 100% CPU. Whether the context continues executing the `while` loop or whether it's doing something else, it'll always do *something*.

Comment: @StephenCleary: yes ok, you're right. I did not write precisely what I meant: yes we'll hit 100%, so this could starve other processes, but I wanted to say that inside our process, we won't eat 100% of the CPU for looping around `!task.IsCompleted` when there are other things to do, so we won't starve other threads inside our process.

Comment: @StephenCleary: one last question, thanks for your time., What about:

`var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

task.ContinueWith(t => { semaphore.Release(); }, cancel);
    
semaphore.Wait(cancel);

task.Wait(cancel);`
?
Any danger doing this if there is an await somewhere before in the call stack?

Comment: @sonatique: That approach re-opens the possibility of deadlocks. There is no solution that works in all scenarios.

Comment: @StephenCleary: thanks a lot! This is what I thought (after posting my question).
I am thinking about a mixed solution for my use case: wrapping the semaphore things within a `while(!task.IsCompleted)` loop and letting the semaphore quit waiting every, say, 100ms, using `semaphore.Wait(100)`.

This would avoid the 100% CPU thing, while avoiding deadlock, at the price of a possible 100ms "temporary deadlock".

Thanks again!

Comment: Be warned that using ConfigureAwait(false) will not preserve the current culture and UI culture. That's why the entity framework staff added the WithCurrentCulture extension.

Comment: @StephenCleary Is there any update to this answer after some years? would you still recommend this solution today?

Comment: @Arvand: I have a more recent [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx) on the subject.

Comment: [Here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html) @StephenCleary explains that GetAwaiter().GetResult() is a good alternative.

Comment: @StephenCleary: I have been reading in [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19696462/2990310) posts that  Task.FromResult can be used to call asynchronous methods in synchronous implementation. Can't we use it in this scenario?

Comment: @Saket: I no longer recommend using it for that, due to the different error handling semantics. See my article on [brownfield async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx) if you absolutely cannot avoid sync-over-async.

Comment: got error Task' does not contain a definition for 'WaitAndUnwrapException' and no accessible extension method 'WaitAndUnwrapException' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   any ideas??

Comment: @bluejayke: Install the [`Nito.AsyncEx`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) library. Alternatively, use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `.WaitAndUnwrapException()`.

Comment: @StephenCleary interesting, I tried .GetAwaiter().GetResult(), but afterwards, I realized that I need a new way of doing it. Meaning insttead of atempting to reporoduce the "await" keyword, I need a way to repordouce the JavaScripts Promise .then, for example, in C#, is there some way to call  an asynchrous function like: myAsyncFunc("hello").Then(r=>/*something*/) ?

Comment: @bluejayke: `await` is the most modern form of `then`. Is there some reason you can't use `await`?

Comment: @StephenCleary await is not the same as then, because await can only be called in an async function, and when calling await, it freezes the main loop; however, "then" is the opposite of await, since, even though you are calling a function that would normally be called with "await", but it can #1 be done in a regular function and #2 not clog up the main loop

Comment: @bluejayke: Both `await` and `then` attach continuations. `await` is a more modern syntax for attaching continuations that handles corner cases well and results in more maintainable code. Calling `then` and then discarding the resulting continuation `Task` is functionally equivalent to calling an `async` method and discarding the returned `Task` (and neither is recommended).

Comment: Would have loved to read this before doing my own thing... which probably is worse and longer... `protected T DoTheSync<T>(Task<T> task) {  try {  return task.Result;  } catch (AggregateException e) when (e.InnerException != null) { ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e.InnerException).Throw();  throw;  } }`  (sorry for not being able to post properly indented code here :-) )

Comment: How about AsyncMethod().RunSynchronously(); ??

Comment: @Macindows: `RunSynchronously` is for delegate tasks; it doesn't work with tasks returned from asynchronous methods.

Comment: Can we use sol 2 or 3 in VM constructor in MVVM which loads UI or sets properties?

Comment: @Morse: I don't recommend blocking UI threads. You should instead show a "Loading..." screen while loading the data.

Comment: @StephenCleary when you say "every await in MyAsyncMethod should end with ConfigureAwait(false)" - do you mean "every await ALL THE WAY DOWN" or just every await at MyAsyncMethod level?

Comment: @AlexfromJitbit Every await all the way down. Every await in MyAsyncMethod and the transitive closure of all methods called from it. Including all third-party libraries and framework code. The obvious problem with that approach is it's easy to miss one.

Comment: @StephenCleary Can you please explain difference b/w below and tell me that which one is least worst ?
#1 Task.Run(() => SomeLibrary.FooAsync()).Result; 
#2 Task.Run(() => SomeLibrary.FooAsync().Result).Result; 
#3 Task.Run(async () => await SomeLibrary.FooAsync()).Result; 
#4 Task.Run(async () => await SomeLibrary.FooAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)).Result;

Comment: @JayShah: I recommend asking your own question, also providing application details. Comments aren't a good medium for giving answers

Answer (score 432):

Adding a solution that finally solved my problem, hopefully saves somebody's time.

Firstly read a couple articles of [Stephen Cleary](http://stephencleary.com/):

- [Async and Await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)
- [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

From the "two best practices" in "Don't Block on Async Code", the first one didn't work for me and the second one wasn't applicable (basically if I can use `await`, I do!).

So here is my workaround: wrap the call inside a `Task.Run<>(async () => await FunctionAsync());` and hopefully no **deadlock** anymore.

Here is my code:

```
public class LogReader
{
    ILogger _logger;

    public LogReader(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public LogEntity GetLog()
    {
        Task<LogEntity> task = Task.Run<LogEntity>(async () => await GetLogAsync());
        return task.Result;
    }

    public async Task<LogEntity> GetLogAsync()
    {
        var result = await _logger.GetAsync();
        // more code here...
        return result as LogEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two years on, I'm curious to know how this solution is holding up.  Any news?  Is there subtlety to this approach that is lost on newbies?

Comment: What happens when there is an exception in `GetLog()` -- does it throw an [AggregateException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: If the exception is inside the `GetLog()` itself, it raises as a normal exception. But if it raises inside `GetLogAsync()`, you can get it from `task.Exception` property. The document is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This won't deadlock, true, but simply because it's forced to run in a new thread, outside of the synchronization context of the originating thread. However, there's certain environments where this is very ill-advised: particularly web applications. This could effectively halve the available threads for the web server (one thread for the request and one for this). The more you do this, the worse it gets. You could potentially end up deadlocking your entire web server.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - You may be right, because `Task.Run()` is not a best practice in an async code. But, again, what's the answer to the original question? Never call an async method synchronously? We wish, but in a real world, sometimes we have to.

Comment: Trying this method on an SqlCommand generates a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException for me: `Task.Run(async () => await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync());` Adding assignments as you did solved the problem: `Task<int> task = Task.Run(async () => await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()); var result = task.Result;`

Comment: @Tohid you could try Stephen Cleary's library. I've seen people assume this  and `Parallel.ForEach` abuse won't have an effect in 'the real world' and eventually it took down the servers. This code is OK for Console apps but as @ChrisPratt says, shouldn't be used in Web Apps. It might work "now" but isn't scalable.

Comment: if `GetLogAsync()` throws an exception we can't simply catch it using a `try / catch` in `GetLog()`. I mean, it will catch the exception, but it won't be the original one.

Comment: @emzero - that's a fallback I guess. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Kinda crazy that .NET 5.0 is out and there's still no bulletproof way to call async methods synchronously.

Comment: What's the difference between `Task<LogEntity> task = Task.Run<LogEntity>(async () => await GetLogAsync()); return task.Result;` and simply `return GetLogAsync().Result;`?

Comment: @JHBonarius In the first case, the task is performed on a background thread and the result is fetched by the originating context, through the `Result` property. In the second case, the task is performed on the same context and will lead to a deadlock if that context is the UI Thread.

Comment: @AsPas yeah thanks. in the past 8 months I learned a lot of C#, so in the mean time I know that. (The hard way, resulting in a deadlock). Still good of you to put it here

Answer (score 313):

Microsoft built an AsyncHelper (internal) class to run Async as Sync.  The source looks like:

```
internal static class AsyncHelper
{
    private static readonly TaskFactory _myTaskFactory = new 
      TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None, 
                  TaskCreationOptions.None, 
                  TaskContinuationOptions.None, 
                  TaskScheduler.Default);

    public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
    {
        return AsyncHelper._myTaskFactory
          .StartNew<Task<TResult>>(func)
          .Unwrap<TResult>()
          .GetAwaiter()
          .GetResult();
    }

    public static void RunSync(Func<Task> func)
    {
        AsyncHelper._myTaskFactory
          .StartNew<Task>(func)
          .Unwrap()
          .GetAwaiter()
          .GetResult();
    }
}
```

The Microsoft.AspNet.Identity base classes only have Async methods and in order to call them as Sync there are classes with extension methods that look like (example usage):

```
public static TUser FindById<TUser, TKey>(this UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager, TKey userId) where TUser : class, IUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    if (manager == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("manager");
    }
    return AsyncHelper.RunSync<TUser>(() => manager.FindByIdAsync(userId));
}

public static bool IsInRole<TUser, TKey>(this UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager, TKey userId, string role) where TUser : class, IUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    if (manager == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("manager");
    }
    return AsyncHelper.RunSync<bool>(() => manager.IsInRoleAsync(userId, role));
}
```

For those concerned about the licensing terms of code, here is a link to very similar code (just adds support for culture on the thread) that has comments to indicate that it is MIT Licensed by Microsoft.  https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/AsyncHelper.cs

> Wouldn't this be the same as just calling Task.Run(async ()=> await AsyncFunc()).Result? AFAIK, Microsoft is now discouraging from calling TaskFactory.StartNew, since they are both equivalent and one is more readable than the other.

Absolutely not.

The easy answer is that

```
.Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult() != .Result
```

First off the

[Is Task.Result the same as .GetAwaiter.GetResult()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult)

Secondly [.Unwrap()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap?view=net-5.0) causes the setup of the Task not to block the wrapped task.

Which should lead anyone to ask

> Wouldn't this be the same as just calling Task.Run(async ()=> await AsyncFunc()).GetAwaiter().GetResult()

Which would then be a *It Depends*.

[Regarding usage of Task.Start() , Task.Run() and Task.Factory.StartNew()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60286230/)

Excerpt:

> Task.Run uses TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach which means that **children's tasks can not be attached to the parent** and it uses TaskScheduler.Default which means that the one that **runs tasks on Thread Pool will always be used** to run tasks.
>
> Task.Factory.StartNew uses TaskScheduler.Current which means scheduler of the current thread, it might be **TaskScheduler.Default but not always**.

Additional Reading:

[Specifying a synchronization context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-5.0#specifying-a-synchronization-context)

[ASP.NET Core SynchronizationContext](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html)

> For extra safety, wouldn't it be better to call it like this `AsyncHelper.RunSync(async () => await AsyncMethod().ConfigureAwait(false));` This way we're telling the "inner" method "please don't try to sync to upper context and dealock"

Really great point by [alex-from-jitbit](/users/56621) and as most object architectural questions go *it depends*.

As an extension method do you want to force that for **absolutely** every call, or do you let the programmer using the function configure that on their own async calls?  I could see a use case for call three scenarios; it most likely is not something you want in WPF, certainly makes sense in most cases, but considering there is no [Context in ASP.Net Core](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) if you could guarantee it was say internal for a ASP.Net Core, then it wouldn't matter.

Comment: My async methods await other async methods.  I do NOT decorate any of my `await` calls with `ConfigureAwait(false)`.  I tried using `AsyncHelper.RunSync` to call an async function from the `Application_Start()` function in Global.asax and it seems to work.  Does this mean that `AsyncHelper.RunSync` is reliably not prone to the "marshal back to the caller's context" deadlock issue I read about elsewhere in this posting?

Comment: @Bob.at.SBS depends on what you code does.  It's not as simple as *if I use this code am I safe*.  This is very minimal and semi-safe way to run async commands synchronously, it can be easily used inappropriately to cause deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks. 2 follow-up questions: 1) Can you give an example of something the async method wants to avoid that would cause a deadlock, and 2) are deadlocks in this context often timing-dependent? If it works in practice, might I still have a timing-dependent deadlock lurking in my code?

Comment: @Bob.at.SBS I would recommend asking question by using the *Ask Question* button at the top right.  You can include a link to this question or answer in your question as a reference.

Comment: `GetAwaiter` does not exist, anyone?

Comment: @Bob.at... the code provided by Erik works perfect under Asp. net mvc5 and EF6, but not when I tried any of the other solutions (ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult() or .result) which hangs completely my web app

Comment: This is the only answer that does not cause deadlocks for my usage scenarios.

Comment: Wouldn't this be the same as just calling `Task.Run(async ()=> await AsyncFunc()).Result`? AFAIK, Microsoft is now discouraging from calling `TaskFactory.StartNew`, since they are both equivalent and one is more readable than the other. Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/

Comment: @ErikPhilips thanks for updating the already great answer. Regarding your last point about ASP.NET Core not having context - well, we do experience thread starvation by using this code as is. And we're not alone: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/2104#issuecomment-337479468 Just for adding context

Comment: @ErikPhilips Can you please explain difference b/w below and tell me that which one is least worst ?
#1 Task.Run(() => SomeLibrary.FooAsync()).Result; 
#2 Task.Run(() => SomeLibrary.FooAsync().Result).Result; 
#3 Task.Run(async () => await SomeLibrary.FooAsync()).Result; 
#4 Task.Run(async () => await SomeLibrary.FooAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)).Result; 

Am I correct to think that #3 is least worst ?

Comment: @JayShah All I will say is that I would never use of those.

Answer (score 268):

`async Main()` is now part of C# 7.2 and can be enabled in the projects advanced build settings.

For C# < 7.2, the correct way is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
   /*await stuff here*/
}
```

You'll see this used in a lot of Microsoft documentation, for example:
[Get started with Azure Service Bus topics and subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions).

Comment: I have no idea WHY someone voted this down.  This worked great for me.  Without this fix, I would have had to propagate ASYCH EVERYWHERE.

Comment: Why is this better than `MainAsync().Wait()`?

Comment: Yeah, there's no reason to it this roundabout way instead of using it like @crush said. However, the problem with this approach is that it does not allow for return types. You'd need more code for that. But the extension methods in the top answer take care of this (and unwraps the exceptions), so is superior to use unless you cannot for some reason.

Comment: I agree. You just need MainAsync().Wait() instead of all this.

Comment: @crush This pattern can help avoid deadlocks in some situations. Results can be returned by switching to .Result.

Comment: @crush If this were a UI app instead of console app* a deadlock could occur trying to .Wait() a task on the UI thread. Task.Run schedules the task to run on the threadpool. Now the await will capture the threadpool's context instead. The .Wait() will synchronously block the UI thread, but the task will complete on the threadpool. This avoids a deadlock *"in some situations".

Comment: @David That's not a deadlock. It's just blocking the UI thread. It'll eventually unblock the UI thread unless the task never completes. Sure, it's better to move the task off the UI thread in that scenario. I don't see how a deadlock occurs though.

Comment: @crush I was describing how this can avoid some deadlocks. In some situations calling .Wait() from a UI or asp.net thread causes a deadlock. [async deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: @ClintB: You should absolutely not do this in ASP.NET Core. Web applications are particularly vulnerable to being thread-starved, and each time you do this, you're pulling a thread from the pool that would otherwise be used to serve a request. It's less problematic for desktop/mobile applications because they're traditionally single-user.

Comment: @ChrisPratt  You mean async shouldn't be used for web applications? using async is all over the ASP.NET Core documentation, is the reason why I am here trying to figure this out. What should we do when the official documentation is the one telling us to use async? for example, I am here because I'm trying to create a ViewComponent and the example they show all the code for is using async. I am confused now.

Comment: @delroh: I think some comments were removed. I'm reasonably sure I was replying to someone suggesting the use of `Task.Run`. Of course you can use async, and in ASP.NET Core, you should virtually always use async.

Comment: This hangs my UWP app.

Comment: This is basically the same as using `.Result`, which can cause Deadlocks. Agree with you guys, in a void Method, call `Wait()`.

Comment: Wait() collects exceptions into an AggregateException, GetAwaiter().GetResult() returns the exception thrown.

Comment: this is async call with synchronous execution

Comment: there is a chance to get some error like this

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=1.14.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: This does not answer the original question which is "How to call async method from sync method?" You just changed the calling method to an async.

Comment: This is the way to go if you are not calling from an UI thread, since it doesn't unnecessarily use more threads.

Comment: This great answer is just the same as the accepted answer from Stephen Cleary, updated for 2021, as in his own comments, but without all the complicated "explanations". Yes, in e.g. web apps this might be not a good practice, async stuff is not invented without reason, but if you need to call an async method in a sync env, this is it.

Answer (score 77):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the technique described in [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/) should work in many circumstances:

> You can thus use `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` if you want to directly invoke this propagation logic.

Comment: Solution A in Stephen Cleary's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9343733/450913) above uses this method. See [WaitAndUnwrapException](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/edb2c6b66d41471008a56e4098f9670b5143617e/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/SynchronousTaskExtensions.cs#L17-L22) source.

Comment: do you need use GetResult()  if the function you are calling is void or task? I mean if you dont want to get any results back

Comment: Yes, otherwise it will not block until task completion. Alternatively instead of calling GetAwaiter().GetResult() you can call .Wait()

Comment: That's the "many circumstances" part. It depends on the overall threading model and what other threads are doing to determine if there's a risk of deadlock or not.

Comment: GetAwaiter().GetResult() can still cause deadlocks. It only unwraps the exception into a more sensible one.

Comment: GetAwaiter().GetResult() causes deadlocks always for me also always.

Comment: @orad yes, it may be using the "solution A" but without any dependencies from a 3rd party lib

Answer (score 68):

```
public async Task<string> StartMyTask()
{
    await Foo()
    // code to execute once foo is done
}

static void Main()
{
     var myTask = StartMyTask(); // call your method which will return control once it hits await
     // now you can continue executing code here
     string result = myTask.Result; // wait for the task to complete to continue
     // use result

}
```

You read the 'await' keyword as "start this long running task, then return control to the calling method". Once the long-running task is done, then it executes the code after it. The code after the await is similar to what used to be CallBack methods. The big difference being the logical flow is not interrupted which makes it much easier to write and read.

Comment: `Wait` wraps exceptions and has the possibility of a deadlock.

Comment: I thought if you called an async method without using `await`, it would be executed synchronously. At least that works for me (without calling `myTask.Wait`). Actually, I got an exception when I tried to call `myTask.RunSynchronously()` because it had already been executed!

Comment: Note: You can then get the result of type `T` by calling myTask.Result() after the Wait()

Comment: Good point. I've changed `Wait()` to `Result` since this will also block until the task is finished.

Comment: Should this answer still work as of today? I just tried it in an MVC Razor project and the app just hangs on accessing `.Result`.

Comment: @awe That's a very special case - your task finished synchronously before it even got to the first `await`, basically - it wasn't asynchronous at all. `RunSynchronously` doesn't really do what most people think it does - you shouldn't really need it, ever. `Result` (and `Wait`) is the thing that synchronously waits for the task to complete - but it gets you in trouble if there's marshalling to the original synchronization context that you're blocking now with your `Wait` :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie That's the synchronization context deadlock. Your async code marshalls back to the synchronization context, but that's being blocked by the `Result` call at the time, so it never gets there. And `Result` never ends, because it's waiting for someone who's waiting for the `Result` to end, basically :D

Answer (score 32):

There is, however, a good solution that works in (almost: see comments) every situation: an ad-hoc message pump (SynchronizationContext).

The calling thread will be blocked as expected, while still ensuring that all continuations called from the async function don't deadlock as they'll be marshaled to the ad-hoc SynchronizationContext (message pump) running on the calling thread.

The code of the ad-hoc message pump helper:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Microsoft.Threading
{
    /// <summary>Provides a pump that supports running asynchronous methods on the current thread.</summary>
    public static class AsyncPump
    {
        /// <summary>Runs the specified asynchronous method.</summary>
        /// <param name="asyncMethod">The asynchronous method to execute.</param>
        public static void Run(Action asyncMethod)
        {
            if (asyncMethod == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("asyncMethod");

            var prevCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            try
            {
                // Establish the new context
                var syncCtx = new SingleThreadSynchronizationContext(true);
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncCtx);

                // Invoke the function
                syncCtx.OperationStarted();
                asyncMethod();
                syncCtx.OperationCompleted();

                // Pump continuations and propagate any exceptions
                syncCtx.RunOnCurrentThread();
            }
            finally { SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(prevCtx); }
        }

        /// <summary>Runs the specified asynchronous method.</summary>
        /// <param name="asyncMethod">The asynchronous method to execute.</param>
        public static void Run(Func<Task> asyncMethod)
        {
            if (asyncMethod == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("asyncMethod");

            var prevCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            try
            {
                // Establish the new context
                var syncCtx = new SingleThreadSynchronizationContext(false);
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncCtx);

                // Invoke the function and alert the context to when it completes
                var t = asyncMethod();
                if (t == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("No task provided.");
                t.ContinueWith(delegate { syncCtx.Complete(); }, TaskScheduler.Default);

                // Pump continuations and propagate any exceptions
                syncCtx.RunOnCurrentThread();
                t.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            finally { SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(prevCtx); }
        }

        /// <summary>Runs the specified asynchronous method.</summary>
        /// <param name="asyncMethod">The asynchronous method to execute.</param>
        public static T Run<T>(Func<Task<T>> asyncMethod)
        {
            if (asyncMethod == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("asyncMethod");

            var prevCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            try
            {
                // Establish the new context
                var syncCtx = new SingleThreadSynchronizationContext(false);
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncCtx);

                // Invoke the function and alert the context to when it completes
                var t = asyncMethod();
                if (t == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("No task provided.");
                t.ContinueWith(delegate { syncCtx.Complete(); }, TaskScheduler.Default);

                // Pump continuations and propagate any exceptions
                syncCtx.RunOnCurrentThread();
                return t.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            finally { SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(prevCtx); }
        }

        /// <summary>Provides a SynchronizationContext that's single-threaded.</summary>
        private sealed class SingleThreadSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
        {
            /// <summary>The queue of work items.</summary>
            private readonly BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object>> m_queue =
                new BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object>>();
            /// <summary>The processing thread.</summary>
            private readonly Thread m_thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            /// <summary>The number of outstanding operations.</summary>
            private int m_operationCount = 0;
            /// <summary>Whether to track operations m_operationCount.</summary>
            private readonly bool m_trackOperations;

            /// <summary>Initializes the context.</summary>
            /// <param name="trackOperations">Whether to track operation count.</param>
            internal SingleThreadSynchronizationContext(bool trackOperations)
            {
                m_trackOperations = trackOperations;
            }

            /// <summary>Dispatches an asynchronous message to the synchronization context.</summary>
            /// <param name="d">The System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback delegate to call.</param>
            /// <param name="state">The object passed to the delegate.</param>
            public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
            {
                if (d == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("d");
                m_queue.Add(new KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object>(d, state));
            }

            /// <summary>Not supported.</summary>
            public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Synchronously sending is not supported.");
            }

            /// <summary>Runs an loop to process all queued work items.</summary>
            public void RunOnCurrentThread()
            {
                foreach (var workItem in m_queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                    workItem.Key(workItem.Value);
            }

            /// <summary>Notifies the context that no more work will arrive.</summary>
            public void Complete() { m_queue.CompleteAdding(); }

            /// <summary>Invoked when an async operation is started.</summary>
            public override void OperationStarted()
            {
                if (m_trackOperations)
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref m_operationCount);
            }

            /// <summary>Invoked when an async operation is completed.</summary>
            public override void OperationCompleted()
            {
                if (m_trackOperations &&
                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_operationCount) == 0)
                    Complete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
AsyncPump.Run(() => FooAsync(...));
```

More detailed description of the async pump is available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/02/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps-part-3.aspx).

Comment: ***Exception context and AsyncPump*** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161693/how-can-i-preserve-exception-context-in-an-async-console-application-using-async

Comment: This doesn't work in an Asp.net scenario, as you can randomly lose HttpContext.Current.

Comment: @JoshMouch Unless you're using a VERY old version of asp.net, you should *never* user HttpContext.Current.

Answer (score 24):

To anyone paying attention to this question anymore...

If you look in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi` there's a class called `TaskExtensions`. Within that class you'll see the static extension method `Task.SyncResult()`, which like totally just blocks the thread till the task returns.

Internally it calls `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` which is pretty simple, however it's overloaded to work on any `async` method that return `Task`, `Task<T>` or `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`... syntactic sugar, baby... daddy's got a sweet tooth.

It looks like `...GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is the MS-official way to execute async code in a blocking context. Seems to work very fine for my use case.

Comment: You had me at "like totally just blocks".

Comment: task.GetAwaiter().GetResult() causes deadlocks always for me.

Answer (score 16):

You can call any asynchronous method from synchronous code, that is, until you need to `await` on them, in which case they have to be marked as `async` too.

As a lot of people are suggesting here, you could call `Wait()` or Result on the resulting task in your synchronous method, but then you end up with a blocking call in that method, which sort of defeats the purpose of async.

If you really can't make your method `async` and you don't want to lock up the synchronous method, then you're going to have to use a callback method by passing it as parameter to the `ContinueWith()` method on task.

Comment: Then that wouldn't be calling the method synchronously now would it?

Comment: As I understand, the question was can you call an async method from a non-async method. This does not imply having to call the async method in a blocking manner.

Comment: Sorry, your "they have to be marked `async` too" drew my attention away from what you were really saying.

Comment: If I don't really care about the asynchronousness, is it OK to call it this way (and what about the possibility of deadlocks in wrapped exceptions that Stephen Cleary keeps nagging about?) I have some test methods (that must be executed synchronously) that tests asynchronous methods. I must wait for the result before continuing, so I can test the result of the asynchronous method.

Answer (score 16):

```
var result = Task.Run(async () => await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync()).ConfigureAwait(false);

OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = result.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Or use this:

```
var result=result.GetAwaiter().GetResult().AccessToken
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is the simplest solution. I saw it somewhere on the Internet, I didn't remember where, but I have been using it successfully. It will not deadlock the calling thread.

```
    void SynchronousFunction()
    {
        Task.Run(Foo).Wait();
    }

    string SynchronousFunctionReturnsString()
    {
        return Task.Run(Foo).Result;
    }

    string SynchronousFunctionReturnsStringWithParam(int id)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Foo(id)).Result;
    }
```

Comment: This will not rethrow the original exception, instead it will fail on something thread related. It is solved in my reply

Answer (score 11):

Stephen Cleary's Answer;

> That approach shouldn't cause a deadlock (assuming that
> ProblemMethodAsync doesn't send updates to the UI thread or anything
> like that). It does assume that ProblemMethodAsync can be called on a
> thread pool thread, which is not always the case.

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

And here is the approach;

> The Thread Pool Hack A similar approach to the Blocking Hack is to
> offload the asynchronous work to the thread pool, then block on the
> resulting task. The code using this hack would look like the code
> shown in Figure 7.
>
> Figure 7 Code for the Thread Pool Hack
>
> C#

```
public sealed class WebDataService : IDataService
{
  public string Get(int id)
  {
    return Task.Run(() => GetAsync(id)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  }
  public async Task<string> GetAsync(int id)
  {
    using (var client = new WebClient())
      return await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(
      "https://www.example.com/api/values/" + id);
  }
}
```

> The call to Task.Run executes the asynchronous method on a thread pool
> thread. Here it will run without a context, thus avoiding the
> deadlock. One of the problems with this approach is the asynchronous
> method can’t depend on executing within a specific context. So, it
> can’t use UI elements or the ASP.NET HttpContext.Current.

Comment: Thank you. Worked for me and is probably the most up-to-date way of achieving this.

Answer (score 9):

Inspired by some of the other answers, I created the following simple helper methods:

```
public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> method)
{
    var task = method();
    return task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public static void RunSync(Func<Task> method)
{
    var task = method();
    task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

They can be called as follows (depending on whether you are returning a value or not):

```
RunSync(() => Foo());
var result = RunSync(() => FooWithResult());
```

Comment: I had to change the method to be like this for it to work:
`return Task.Run(async () => await method()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: @herdsothom that's because in your case `method()` is actually an asyncrounous method itself - while in @Metalogic's example `foo()` is a syncrounous method that he is calling asyncrounously. In your case simply `method().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` should sufice

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias, I've updated my answer as suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Well I was using this approach for years, which also handles and propagates exceptions from the underlying async task. Which works flawlessly.

```
private string RunSync()
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () => await GenerateCodeService.GenerateCodeAsync());
    if (task.IsFaulted && task.Exception != null)
    {
        throw task.Exception;
    }

    return task.Result;
}
```

But since that Microsoft created this async helper: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/AsyncHelper.cs

Here is also their source:

```
public static void RunSync(Func<Task> func)
        {
            var cultureUi = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
            var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            _myTaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureUi;
                return func();
            }).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
```

Comment: Works with   return task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: .Result i think is the same basically as .GetAwaiter().GetResult()

Comment: well it is not, because usual .Result without awaiting it, could lead to a deadlock.

Comment: This causes deadlocks for me, sorry. The AsyncHelper answer seems to be the only one that does not.

Comment: @Aidan source code sample for that deadlock ?

Comment: @Aidan it does not cause deadlock, it just waits until your inner method finishes it's job.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use source generators to create a sync version of your method using [Sync Method Generator](https://github.com/zompinc/sync-method-generator) library ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zomp.SyncMethodGenerator)).

Use it as follows:

```cs
[Zomp.SyncMethodGenerator.CreateSyncVersion]
public async Task FooAsync()
```

Which will generate `Foo` method which you can call synchronously.

Comment: Interesting approach but I think this should only be used if you are calling another method you have written. The reason is [this](https://github.com/zompinc/sync-method-generator#:~:text=Remove%20asynchronous%20invocations%20without%20the%20Async%20suffix) line(`Remove asynchronous invocations without the Async suffix`) from the main GitHub page because you're not the author this feature can definitely introduce bugs. Since there are APIs out there that only support Async API this unfortunately is not a universal solution to OP's question.

Comment: When a library has async API only, this indeed won't work and that invocation will get dropped. The way to currently handle it is with #if SYNC_ONLY special macro.

Answer (score -3):

Everyone seems to presuppose that there is a need to wait for the result.
I often have to update data from synchronous methods where I don't care about the result. I just use a discard:

```
_ = UpdateAsync();
```

Comment: this is wrong sorry, it means, it's not guaranteed, that the code inside will run to an end.
if the main() will reach an end of execution, it will not look after the code inside if it's done or not, and will just shut it down.

Comment: @JiříHerník I have a project where data lists (tables that the usere sees and uses to pick existing records) in the client are loaded async. Why should it matter if the code finishes before the user closes the application? Maybe "wait for the result" isn't the best possible expression...

Comment: The code inside not awaited async task is not quarantined to finish. That is all.