# Preventing a deadlock when calling an async method without using await

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0, async-await

I need to call a method returning a `Task` from within

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

It wont let me make this method async it throws the following

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending.

and when calling

```
 entityStorage.GetCurrentUser().Result
```

I get a deadlock. How can I avoid this?

I have been playing around with it coming up with stuff like

```
entityStorage.GetCurrentUser().Result.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

But this isn't working. How can I do it? My solution will need to work with ASP.NET 4 and the Async Targetting Pack, I can't use ASP.NET 4.5 as am deploying to Azure.

Comment: Found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097066/168012 if anyone has a better solution please share

Comment: Are you deriving from `AsyncController` instead of `Controller`?

Comment: Please [vote here](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/9582) for the MVC team to add support for `async` action filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since await is just syntax sugar for the compiler rewriting a continuation for you, the most 'direct' path would be to take whatever code was going to follow your await and make it a ContinueWith call.

So, something like:

```
entityStorage.GetCurrentUser().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    // do your other stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 13):

The cause of the deadlock is [explained here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). In short, don't block on `async` code. You should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in your library `async` code and `await` the results (not use `Result` or `Wait`).

**Update:** Please [vote here](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/9582) for the MVC team to add support for `async` action filters.

Comment: I'm having a hard time find the link/page that says so, but I've had others tell me in the past that if providing a link (especially one external to SO) that you should copy the key bits into the SO answer.  It's somewhat mentioned here, though, FWIW: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer

Comment: You are correct; the meta question you're referring to was recently deleted as part of the "let's make SO a nicer place" strategy. However, as Jon Skeet commented: if I know the answer and only have time to post a link, it's better than nothing.

Comment: The problem I had is that if I tried to use the async keyword and make the method async then the method threw 'An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.'

Comment: ASP.NET is telling you that you can't use asynchronous methods there. You can kind of force it using `ContinueWith`, but that brings its own problems in ASP.NET.

Comment: OK, so is there a good solution to doing this without using .NET 4.5? The only other solution I found was the one I put as a comment to the question, which I actually ended up using as I needed to store a cookie after the call which wasn't possible when using ContinueWith

Comment: The core problem is that you aren't *supposed* to do asynchronous processing in `OnActionExecuting`. I think the cleanest way to force it is to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` inside `GetCurrentUser` and then use [`WaitAndUnwrapException`](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/) to block on the `Task` returned by `GetCurrentUser`.

Answer (score 0):

If you **MUST** convert asynch to synch.

```
public User GetCurrentUserSynch()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var asyncResult = entityStorage.GetCurrentUser();
            while (!asyncResult.IsCompleted)
            {
                Application.Current.TryFindResource(new object()); // This is for WPF but you can do some other nonsense action of your choosing
            }

            return asyncResult.Result;
        }).Result;
    }
```

Otherwise use @Stephen's answer.