# Different behavior when using ContinueWith or Async-Await

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, async-await

When I use an async-await method (as the example below) in a HttpClient call, this code causes a **deadlock**. Replacing the async-await method with a `t.ContinueWith`, it works properly. Why?

```
public class MyFilter: ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
         var user = _authService.GetUserAsync(username).Result;
    }
}

public class AuthService: IAuthService {
    public async Task<User> GetUserAsync (string username) {           
        var jsonUsr = await _httpClientWrp.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<User>(jsonUsr);
    }
}
```

**This works:**

```
public class HttpClientWrapper : IHttpClient {
    public Task<string> GetStringAsync(string url) {           
        return _client.GetStringAsync(url).ContinueWith(t => {
                _log.InfoFormat("Response: {0}", url);                    
                return t.Result;
        });
}
```

**This code will deadlock:**

```
public class HttpClientWrapper : IHttpClient {
    public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string url) {       
        string result = await _client.GetStringAsync(url);
        _log.InfoFormat("Response: {0}", url);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I describe this deadlock behavior [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

- `await` will by default schedule its continuation to run inside the current `SynchronizationContext`, or (if there is no `SynchronizationContext`) the current `TaskScheduler`. (Which in this case is the ASP.NET request `SynchronizationContext`).
- The ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext` represents the request context, and ASP.NET only allows one thread in that context at a time.

So, when the HTTP request completes, it attempts to enter the `SynchronizationContext` to run `InfoFormat`. However, there is already a thread in the `SynchronizationContext` - the one blocked on `Result` (waiting for the `async` method to complete).

On the other hand, the default behavior for `ContinueWith` by default will schedule its continuation to the current `TaskScheduler` (which in this case is the thread pool `TaskScheduler`).

As others have noted, it's best to use `await` "all the way", i.e., don't block on `async` code. Unfortunately, that's not an option in this case since [MVC does not support asynchronous action filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482338/async-action-filter-in-mvc-4) (as a side note, please [vote for this support here](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/9582)).

So, your options are to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` or to just use synchronous methods. In this case, I recommend synchronous methods. `ConfigureAwait(false)` only works if the `Task` it's applied to has not already completed, so I recommend that once you use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, you should use it for every `await` in the method after that point (and in this case, in each method in the call stack). If `ConfigureAwait(false)` is being used for efficiency reasons, then that's fine (because it's technically optional). In this case, `ConfigureAwait(false)` would be necessary for correctness reasons, so IMO it creates a maintenance burden. Synchronous methods would be clearer.

Answer (score 7):

### An explanation on why your await deadlocks

Your first line:

```
 var user = _authService.GetUserAsync(username).Result;
```

blocks that thread and the current context while it waits for the result of `GetUserAsync`.

When using `await` it attempts to run any remaining statements back on the original context after the task being waited on finishes, which causes deadlocks if the original context is blocked (which is is because of the `.Result`).  It looks like you attempted to preempt this problem by using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in `GetUserAsync`, however by the time that that `await` is in effect it's too late because another `await` is encountered first.  The actual execution path looks like this:

```
_authService.GetUserAsync(username)
_httpClientWrp.GetStringAsync(url)   // not actually awaiting yet (it needs a result before it can be awaited)
await _client.GetStringAsync(url)    // here's the first await that takes effect
```

When `_client.GetStringAsync` finishes, the rest of the code can't continue on the original context because that context is blocked.

### Why ContinueWith behaves differently

`ContinueWith` doesn't try to run the other block on the original context (unless you tell it to with an additional parameter) and thus does not suffer from this problem.

This is the difference in behavior that you noticed.

### A solution with async

If you still want to use `async` instead of `ContinueWith`, you can add the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to the first encountered `async`:

```
string result = await _client.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

which as you most likely already know, tells `await` not to try to run the remaining code on the original context.

### Note for the future

Whenever possible, attempt to not use blocking methods when using async/await.  See [Preventing a deadlock when calling an async method without using await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887915/preventing-a-deadlock-when-calling-an-async-method-without-using-await?rq=1) for avoiding this in the future.

Comment: “it attempts to run any remaining statements back on the original thread” That's not exactly true, it attempts to run them on the original *context*. In ASP.NET, the context is not tied to a specific thread, so the continuation can execute on a different thread. But you're still going to get the deadlock, because only one thread can be in the context at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Granted, my answer is only partial, but I'll go ahead with it anyway.

Your `Task.ContinueWith(...)` call does not specify the scheduler, therefore `TaskScheduler.Current` will be used - whatever that is at the time. Your `await` snippet, however, will run on the captured context when the awaited task completes, so the two bits of code *may or may not* produce similar behaviour - depending on the value of `TaskScheduler.Current`.

If, say, your first snippet is called from the UI code directly (in which case `TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default`, the continuation (logging code) will execute on the default `TaskScheduler` - that is, on the thread pool.

In the second snippet, however, the continuation (logging) will actually run on the UI thread regardless of whether you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the task returned by GetStringAsync, or not. `ConfigureAwait(false)` will only affect the execution of the code *after* the call to `GetStringAsync` is awaited.

Here's something else to illustrate this:

```
    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await this.Blah().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // InvalidOperationException here.
        this.Text = "Oh noes, I'm no longer on the UI thread.";
    }

    private async Task Blah()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        this.Text = "Hi, I'm on the UI thread.";
    }
```

The given code sets the Text within Blah() just fine, but it throws a cross-threading exception inside the continuation in the Load handler.

Comment: `await` primarily looks at `SynchronizationContext.Current`, not `TaskScheduler.Current`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the other solutions posted here did not work for me on ASP .NET MVC 5, which still uses synchronous Action Filters.  The posted solutions don't guarantee a new thread will be used, they just specify that the same thread does not HAVE to be used.

My solution is to use Task.Factory.StartNew() and specifying TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning in the method call.  This ensures a new/different thread is always used, so you can be assured you will never get a deadlock.

So, using the OP example, the following is the solution that works for me:

```
public class MyFilter: ActionFilterAttribute {
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
     // var user = _authService.GetUserAsync(username).Result;

     // Guarantees a new/different thread will be used to make the enclosed action
     // avoiding deadlocking the calling thread
     var user = Task.Factory.StartNew(
          () => _authService.GetUserAsync(username).Result,
          TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Result;
}
```

}