# Cast Task<T> to T using reflection

Tags: c#, asynchronous, reflection, casting, synchronous

Using method attributes, I get an `IEnumerable<Delegate>`. I want to call each one, now I use `DynamicInvoke` and get the result. However, some of the methods can be `async` and return a `Task` of something. I don't really care what that something is, I just want serialize it using Newtonsoft.

How can I handle both synchronous and asynchronous methods?

I was thinking of checking if the return type implements `Task` or `Task<T>` but since I don't know `T` I'm not sure this would be a good way of doing it.

Right now, my code does not support asynchronous methods and looks like this:

```
protected string Invoke(Delegate method, params object[] args) {
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(method.DynamicInvoke(args));
}

protected void onRequest(Request request) {
   // Some logic
   Send(Invoke(request.Method, request.Arguments));
}
```

The methods look like this:

```
[RequestHandler("sell")]
private async Task<SellResponse> Sell(SellItemRequest request) {
   // Some asynchonous logic
   var response = new SellResponse {
      sucess = true,
      price = request.Price
   };
   return response;
}

[RequestHandler("buy")]
private BuyResponse Buy(BuyItemRequest request) {
   // Some logic
   var response = new {
      sucess = true,
      price = request.Price
   };
   return response;
}
...
```

Comment: can i see the entire method? :)

Comment: @jPhizzle This is extremely oversimplifed code, I will add more details to the example though.

Comment: also... JsonConvert.SerializeObject() returns a string.. so Task<string> would be the one to use....

Comment: @jPhizzle: I think what he meas is that `args` is a delegate that can be either synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `method` could either refer back to `Sell` or `Buy` for example, one of which is async and the other isn't.

Comment: [How can I tell if a C# method is async/await via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350397/how-can-i-tell-if-a-c-sharp-method-is-async-await-via-reflection)

Comment: At some point in this process there's got to be something that causes a call to either the synchronous or async method. Can you make the determination there? It's far easier to decide what to do with the return value of a method when you decide to call it, as opposed to passing around a method that could return one thing or an entirely different thing, and then trying to figure out what the method returns after you call it. For example, instead of passing `IEnumerable<Delegate>`, invoke them and then pass around an `IEnumerable<WhateverTheyReturn>`.

Comment: @ScottHannen I can't, as seen in the example they return different types, some don't return anything. I wouldn't be asking this question otherwise.

Comment: well, why not make Buy() an async method as well? and whatever other methods you may call. make them all async, that way you can just `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(await method.DynamicInvoke(args));`

Comment: @jPhizzle I'm working with a big legacy project, going through 20 something files and all their methods won't pass. It would also, most likely, be a breaking change.