# Await an async void method call for unit testing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, async-await, void

I have a method that looks like this:

```
private async void DoStuff(long idToLookUp)
{
    IOrder order = await orderService.LookUpIdAsync(idToLookUp);   

    // Close the search
    IsSearchShowing = false;
}    

//Other stuff in case you want to see it
public DelegateCommand<long> DoLookupCommand{ get; set; }
ViewModel()
{
     DoLookupCommand= new DelegateCommand<long>(DoStuff);
}
```

I am trying to unit test it like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDoStuff()
{
    //+ Arrange
    myViewModel.IsSearchShowing = true;

    // container is my Unity container and it setup in the init method.
    container.Resolve<IOrderService>().Returns(orderService);
    orderService = Substitute.For<IOrderService>();
    orderService.LookUpIdAsync(Arg.Any<long>())
                .Returns(new Task<IOrder>(() => null));

    //+ Act
    myViewModel.DoLookupCommand.Execute(0);

    //+ Assert
    myViewModel.IsSearchShowing.Should().BeFalse();
}
```

My assert is called before I get done with the mocked up LookUpIdAsync.  In my normal code, that is just what I want.  But for my Unit test I don't want that.

I am converting to Async/Await from using BackgroundWorker.  With background worker this was functioning correctly because I could wait for the BackgroundWorker to finish.

But there does not seem to be a way to wait for a async void method...

**How can I unit test this method?**

Comment: Related: [Wait for an async void method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636648/wait-for-an-async-void-method).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it for unit testing:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDoStuff()
{
    //+ Arrange
    myViewModel.IsSearchShowing = true;

    // container is my Unity container and it setup in the init method.
    container.Resolve<IOrderService>().Returns(orderService);
    orderService = Substitute.For<IOrderService>();

    var lookupTask = Task<IOrder>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                  {
                                      return new Order();
                                  });

    orderService.LookUpIdAsync(Arg.Any<long>()).Returns(lookupTask);

    //+ Act
    myViewModel.DoLookupCommand.Execute(0);
    lookupTask.Wait();

    //+ Assert
    myViewModel.IsSearchShowing.Should().BeFalse();
}
```

The key here is that because I am unit testing I can substitute in the task I want to have my async call (inside my async void) to return.  I then just make sure the task has completed before I move on.

Comment: Just because your `lookupTask` has finished, doesn't mean the method under test (`DoStuff`? or `DoLookupCommand`?) has finished running. There is a small chance that the task has finished running, but `IsSearchShowing` hasn't been set to false yet, in which case your assertion would fail.

Comment: An easy way to prove this would be to put `Thread.Sleep(2000)` before setting `IsSearchShowing ` to false.

Answer (score 80):

You should avoid `async void`. Only use `async void` for event handlers. `DelegateCommand` is (logically) an event handler, so you can do it like this:

```
// Use [InternalsVisibleTo] to share internal methods with the unit test project.
internal async Task DoLookupCommandImpl(long idToLookUp)
{
  IOrder order = await orderService.LookUpIdAsync(idToLookUp);   

  // Close the search
  IsSearchShowing = false;
}

private async void DoStuff(long idToLookUp)
{
  await DoLookupCommandImpl(idToLookup);
}
```

and unit test it as:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestDoStuff()
{
  //+ Arrange
  myViewModel.IsSearchShowing = true;

  // container is my Unity container and it setup in the init method.
  container.Resolve<IOrderService>().Returns(orderService);
  orderService = Substitute.For<IOrderService>();
  orderService.LookUpIdAsync(Arg.Any<long>())
              .Returns(new Task<IOrder>(() => null));

  //+ Act
  await myViewModel.DoLookupCommandImpl(0);

  //+ Assert
  myViewModel.IsSearchShowing.Should().BeFalse();
}
```

---

My recommended answer is above. But if you really want to test an `async void` method, you can do so with my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDoStuff()
{
  AsyncContext.Run(() =>
  {
    //+ Arrange
    myViewModel.IsSearchShowing = true;

    // container is my Unity container and it setup in the init method.
    container.Resolve<IOrderService>().Returns(orderService);
    orderService = Substitute.For<IOrderService>();
    orderService.LookUpIdAsync(Arg.Any<long>())
                .Returns(new Task<IOrder>(() => null));

    //+ Act
    myViewModel.DoLookupCommand.Execute(0);
  });

  //+ Assert
  myViewModel.IsSearchShowing.Should().BeFalse();
}
```

But this solution changes the `SynchronizationContext` for your view model during its lifetime.

Comment: This would work.  But I would rather not have to have two methods for all my async voids.  I figured a way to do it (at least in my case).  See my answer on this question if you are interested.

Comment: Nice - you've created the C# predecessor of https://github.com/btford/zone.js/ ZoneJS.

Comment: What is the benefit of awaiting DoLookupCommandImpl(idToLookup) in DoStuff(long idToLookUp)? What if it would be called without awaiting?

Comment: @jacekbe: `await`ing the task observes exceptions; if you call it without `await`, then any failures are silently ignored.

Answer (score 64):

An `async void` method is essentially a "fire and forget" method.  There is no means of getting back a completion event (without an external event, etc).

If you need to unit test this, I would recommend making it an `async Task` method instead.  You can then call `Wait()` on the results, which will notify you when the method completes.

However, this test method as written would still not work, as you're not actually testing `DoStuff` directly, but rather testing a `DelegateCommand` which wraps it.  You would need to test this method directly.

Comment: I can't change it to return Task because the DelegateCommand will not allow that.

Comment: Having a unit test scaffolding around my code is very important.  I may have to make all (important) "async void" methods use BackgroundWorker if they can't be unit tested.

Comment: @Vaccano The same thing would happen with BackgroundWorker - you just need to make this an `async Task` instead of `async void`, and wait on the task...

Comment: @Vaccano You should have no `async void` methods (except for event handlers). If an exception is raised in `async void` method, how are you going to handle it?

Comment: I figured out a way to make it work (at least for this case).  See my answer on this question if you are interested.

Comment: `async void` is more [fire-and-crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659603/async-void-asp-net-and-count-of-outstanding-operations/17660475#17660475 "Async Void, ASP.Net, and Count of Outstanding Operations") than fire-and-forget. Any error in an `async void` method is rethrown on the captured synchronization context, which usually terminates the process.

Answer (score 9):

The only way I know is to turn your `async void` method to `async Task` method

Answer (score 5):

You can use an AutoResetEvent to halt the test method until the async call completes:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void Async_Test()
{
    TypeToTest target = new TypeToTest();
    AutoResetEvent AsyncCallComplete = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    SuccessResponse SuccessResult = null;
    Exception FailureResult = null;

    target.AsyncMethodToTest(
        (SuccessResponse response) =>
        {
            SuccessResult = response;
            AsyncCallComplete.Set();
        },
        (Exception ex) =>
        {
            FailureResult = ex;
            AsyncCallComplete.Set();
        }
    );

    // Wait until either async results signal completion.
    AsyncCallComplete.WaitOne();
    Assert.AreEqual(null, FailureResult);
}
```

Comment: any AsyncMethodToTest class sample ?

Comment: Why not just use Wait() ?

Answer (score 5):

The provided answer tests the command and not the async method. As mentioned above you'll need another test to test that async method as well.

After spending some time with a similar problem i found an easy wait to test an async method in a unit test by just calling in synchronously:

```
    protected static void CallSync(Action target)
    {
        var task = new Task(target);
        task.RunSynchronously();
    }
```

and the usage:

```
CallSync(() => myClass.MyAsyncMethod());
```

The test waits on this line and continues after the result is ready so we can assert immediately afterwards.

Comment: Are you sure that RunSynchronously() can wait until async void has finished ?

Answer (score 2):

Change your method to return a Task and you can use Task.Result

```
bool res = configuration.InitializeAsync(appConfig).Result;
Assert.IsTrue(res);
```

Comment: what is `configuration` ?

Comment: @Dementic An example? Or more specific an instance of an object with a member InitializeAsync that returns a task.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a different approach, something that was suggested in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void

All your `async void` method does is call this `async Task` method internally.

```
private async void DoStuff(long idToLookUp)
{
    await DoStuffAsync(idLookUp).ConfigureAwait(false);
} 

internal async Task DoStuffAsync(long idToLookUp) //Note: make sure to expose Internal to your test project
{
    IOrder order = await orderService.LookUpIdAsync(idToLookUp);   

    // Close the search
    IsSearchShowing = false;
}
```

And then, instead of calling the `async void` method in my test, I called the `async Task` method.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestDoStuff()
{
  //+ Arrange

  //+ Act
  await myViewModel.DoStuffAsync(0);

  //+ Assert

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. In my case, the solution was to use `Task.FromResult` in the moq setup for `.Returns(...)` like so:

```
orderService.LookUpIdAsync(Arg.Any<long>())
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(null));
```

Alternatively, Moq also has a `ReturnsAysnc(...)` method.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes Wait doesn't work with test cases when you run multiple individual task in your actual implementation.

**The Code:**

```
private async void DoStuff(long idToLookUp)
    {
        IOrder order = await orderService.LookUpIdAsync(idToLookUp).Wait();
        IsSearchShowing = false;
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a comment on other answers? It doesn’t seem like an answer. If I’m misunderstanding, please [edit] your answer to provide clarification.