# How to execute async 'fire and forget' operation in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

So, I have this Web API action, that executes an asynchronous function.

```
public void Post([FromBody]InsertRequest request)
{
    InsertPostCommand.Execute(request);
    DoAsync();
}

private async void DoAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //do async stuff here
    });
}
```

I actually want the controller action to return to the client whilst the async operation executes.

I did this and I am getting an exception thus:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.
```

How can I achieve this please ??

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659603/async-void-asp-net-and-count-of-outstanding-operations

Comment: A good question. But read carefully all the answers provided. Multithreading is tricky in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are asking to do is [extremely dangerous](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx). I have a [blog post that explains why this is a bad idea, including code for a `BackgroundTaskManager` type that minimizes the chance that something will go horribly wrong](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html). Unfortunately, even when you register your background work with the ASP.NET runtime, it's still a bad idea to depend on this behavior.

The proper solution is to have your WebAPI request place a request into a reliable queue (such as Azure Queue), and have an independent service (such as an Azure Worker Role) process that queue.