# ASP MVC app resets on long running thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my ASP MVC 5 app I have this database related operation that I've to perform once in month maybe and it takes about 30 - 60 minutes.
I start this action like this:

```
    Repository dbForCategories = new Repository();
        dbForCategories.Database.CommandTimeout = 60000;
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async delegate
        {
            var crs = new ProductCategoryRelationsSetter(dbForCategories, categoryService);
            crs.AddProductsCategoriesRelations(oneLineTree);

        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

After about 5 minutes of working in background Im getting logged out of application. I think that the app resets because some static variables Im using are reset.
In elmah i don't have any errors. I put my code in Try Catch block.

Only hope in you guys:)

Comment: `"operation that I've to perform once in month maybe and it takes about 30 - 60 minutes"` - This is *not* a task for a web application.  This is a task for a scheduled Console Application or perhaps a Windows Service.

Comment: or using a task scheduler library for ASP.NET MVC like as https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler

Answer (score 6):

As @David mentioned, it's probably best to go the `Windows Service` route:

- Write the item to a database table
- Let a `Windows Service` poll the table every month (or however often you need it to).
- If it finds a new item in the queue, let the `Windows Service` perform the operation.

**Why not do Background threads in ASP.NET?**

The server may recycle Application pool at some point and will not know to wait for your `Task` on a separate thread. ([Discussed in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918728/how-to-execute-async-fire-and-forget-operation-in-asp-net-web-api))

**.NET 4.5.2 onward. You can fire and forget *short tasks***

For interest sake you can use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx)) and the server will respect the background item and not recyle the App pool while it's busy, **BUT ONLY for up to 90 seconds.** anything longer and `Windows Service` is your best bet.

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => yourAsyncWork(ct));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hangfire is wonderful for stuff like this.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire/