# Can an async method override a method in a base class that's not async in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's a base class that I have:

```
public abstract class BaseContentPage : ContentPage
{

    protected BaseContentPage(in IAnalyticsService analyticsService,
                                in IMainThread mainThread,
                                in bool shouldUseSafeArea = false)
    {
        MainThread = mainThread;
        AnalyticsService = analyticsService;

        this.DynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty, nameof(BaseTheme.PageBackgroundColor));

        On<iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(shouldUseSafeArea);
        On<iOS>().SetModalPresentationStyle(UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet);
    }

    protected IAnalyticsService AnalyticsService { get; }
    protected IMainThread MainThread { get; }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        AnalyticsService.Track($"{GetType().Name} Appeared");
    }
```

This is later used like this:

```
public class SplashScreenPage : BaseContentPage
{

    readonly Label _loadingLabel;
    readonly Image _gitTrendsImage;
    readonly FirstRunService _firstRunService;
    readonly AppInitializationService _appInitializationService;
    public SplashScreenPage(IMainThread mainThread,
                                FirstRunService firstRunService,
                                IAnalyticsService analyticsService,
                                AppInitializationService appInitializationService)
        : base(analyticsService, mainThread)
    {
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await ChangeLabelText(_statusMessageEnumerator.Current);
```

My questions are I think both about the same thing:

a) Is it okay to override a non-async method with an async method when used in this way in Xamarin Forms?

b) I know Xamarin calls a normal OnAppearing but will it call an async OnAppearing in the same way?

Comment: async is not actually part of the method signature, so it does not impact your ability to override a base method.  "OnAppearing" and "async OnAppearing" will both work

Comment: check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817558/why-does-c-sharp-allow-making-an-override-async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` is an implementation detail. If you have a base method that returns `Task`, then you can override it with `async Task` whether or not the base method uses `async`.

This is a special case because the return type is `void`. In most cases, [you should avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). `async void` should really only be used for event handlers.

In this specific case (`OnAppearing`), the method is logically an event handler. So in this specific case, overriding with `async void` is probably fine. Just bear in mind that the UI will return to its message loop at each `await`.