# How to invoke async methods in Hangfire?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, hangfire

I have asp.net core API application and this is the first time i will be using HangFire.

In .Net Core application all my methods are async. Based on [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655143/what-are-the-circumstances-of-using-wait-when-calling-async-methods) it's not good idea to use `wait()` while calling async method in hangfire.
Also as per the [hangfire support issue](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/150) in v1.6.0, async support was added. I am using version 1.6.12 but still i dont see async support.

How do i call async method from `Enqueue`. Currently i am using `wait()`

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly Downloader _downlaoder;
    private readonly IBackgroundJobClient _backgroungJobClient;
    public MyController(Downloader downloader, IBackgroundJobClient backgroungJobClient)
    {
        _downlaoder = downloader;
        _backgroungJobClient = backgroungJobClient;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        _backgroungJobClient.Enqueue(() => _downloader.DownloadAsync(files).Wait());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Based on one of the examples on the [repository on github](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/samples/ConsoleSample/Program.cs#L81)

Just remove the `Wait` blocking call

```
_backgroungJobClient.Enqueue(() => _downloader.DownloadAsync(files));
```

The method knows now how to handle Func that returns Task

[Hangfire 1.6.0 - Blog](http://hangfire.io/blog/2016/07/16/hangfire-1.6.0.html)

> The enqueueing logic is the same for sync and async methods. In early
>   betas there was a warning CS4014, but now you can remove all the
>   `#pragma` warning disable statements. It was implemented by using `Expression<Func<Task>>` parameter overloads.
>
> ```
> BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => HighlightAsync(snippet.Id));
> ```

**Note:**

> ### That’s not a real asynchrony
>
> Please consider this feature as a syntactic sugar. Background
>   processing hasn’t became asynchronous. Internally it was implemented
>   using the Task.Wait method, so workers don’t perform any processing,
>   while waiting for a task completion. Real asynchrony may come in
>   Hangfire 2.0 only, and it requires a lot of breaking changes to the
>   existing types.

Comment: Good answer (up-voted you). One thing to point out from their documentation "Real asynchrony may come in Hangfire 2.0 only, and it requires a lot of breaking changes to the existing types." http://hangfire.io/blog/2016/07/16/hangfire-1.6.0.html

Comment: Found it after read a little further down. it was in the same blog article i linked to in the answer. thanks.

Comment: Same for recurring tasks?

Comment: Never use ConfigureAwait(bool) with _downloader.DownloadAsync(files) or you will keep inviting problems.