# Should I use async/await in Hangfire job ?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, hangfire

I recently started using [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) to handle my background jobs in an ASP.NET project.

My jobs are involving lots, lots (and lots) of HTTP calls using `WebRequest` (I may migrate to something else, but that's for later).

While browsing SO on this subject, [I stumbled upon people who do async calls in hangfire.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103092/how-to-invoke-async-methods-in-hangfire)

Is there any point in using `async/await` tasks inside a Hangfire job ? I'm aware that it is a queue, so jobs won't execute concurrently, but since my project has no GUI, is there any reason I would use `async/await` to do my HTTP calls inside a Hangfire job ?

PS : The requests that are involving a long-running job use the [Task](https://farazdagi.com/2014/rest-and-long-running-jobs/) "design pattern", so clients won't experience any timeout

Answer (score 4):

You can absolutely use Hangfire to run async methods, and use awaits within those async methods.

The SO question you linked to was making a blocking `Wait` call on the method passed to Hangfire to be serialized and then later executed by the hangfire service.

This is very different from something like

```
hangfireClient.Enqueue(() => myClass.RunAsync());
```

where `RunAsync` is an `async` method that contains `awaits`.

```
public async Task<bool> RunAsync() {
    //do your work
    var subJob = new worker();
    return await subJob.DoWork();
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'm ok with the fact that I could do it, but my question was more on **why would I do that** ?

Comment: Why would you use Hangfire to execute an async Job?  Same reason you would ever use an async method. If the job your executing is more efficient being async. I can give you an example. I use Hangfire to begin integration transactions which involves syncing multiple independent items. Each one of these items’ sync is an async job, and I await their completion within the Hangfire job.

Comment: Oh okay, I see with your example how it could be more efficient. But if I only do strictly sequential computations in my jobs, they won't be more efficient if executed in async, so I guess it's not any useful to do it in async

Comment: Yep!  Hangfire _really_ is a "fire-and-forget" tool, don't let the fact that you kick off methods with tasks confuse you, it's just storing a method and re-executing it at a later time exactly as if you ran it on your machine right then.

Comment: According to documentation for v 1.6.0  https://www.hangfire.io/blog/2016/07/16/hangfire-1.6.0.html#thats-not-a-real-asynchrony (current is 1.6.20) real aync support would be only in 2.0 release, and currently Task.Wait is under the hood:   Please consider this feature as a syntactic sugar. Background processing hasn’t became asynchronous. Internally it was implemented using the Task.Wait method, so workers don’t perform any processing, while waiting for a task completion. Real asynchrony may come in Hangfire 2.0 only, and it requires a lot of breaking changes to the existing types.