# Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples - InvalidOperationException (MVC 5)

Tags: owin, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

How to debug this error? I can step through the whole request without getting any error. 
EventViewer does not reveal more details.
At the end it shows this error page:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> **An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending.**
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous
>   module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still
>   pending.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler
>   completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.]
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0

Controller called:

```
// POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                user.Claims.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim() { ClaimType = "SOrientation", ClaimValue = "Derpe", UserId = user.Id });

                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    /// enables two factor auth for this user
                    /// registration of twofact auth providers in identityConfig.cs/UserManager.Create
                    await UserManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user.Id, true);

                    var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

                    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

                    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");

                    ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;

                    return View("DisplayEmail");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

The controller action runs through without any problems!

I narrowed down the problem to this async method call:

```
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync
```

which calls this method:

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage m)
{
    var c = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    //c.SendCompleted += MailSendCompleted;
    c.EnableSsl = true;
    c.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    //c.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    c.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("jxxx@gmail.com", "xxx");
    c.SendAsync("xxx@gmail.de", m.Destination, m.Subject, m.Body, m.Destination);

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

What's wrong with the method?

While the follwoing code works, will it run async?

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage m)
{
    var c = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    //c.SendCompleted += MailSendCompleted;
    c.EnableSsl = true;
    c.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    //c.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    c.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("jxxx@gmail.com", "xxx");
    var t = Task.Run(() => c.Send("xx@gmx.de", m.Destination, m.Subject, m.Body));
     await t;
}
```

Comment: When I change the smtp client to use the sync send method:
`c.Send` then it works.

Comment: Try awaiting the `x.SendAsync`

Comment: It's a void method...

Comment: I'll write an answer in a bit with a working method for you.

Comment: While the added code at the end of the question works, I actually don't want to await a fire and forget method....

Comment: I see what you're after now. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/17660475/3274800 for an explanation on async void by Stephen Cleary.