# lock-statement in a Timer callback = potential thread starvation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, threadpool

My library has multiple Timers (can be hundreds), that all call the same logic (it's a cache cleanup but that's not important).

This logic is pretty CPU-intensive, so I introduced a `lock` statement, to prevent multiple threads loading CPU at once:

```
_timer = new Timer(EvictExpiredItems, null, interval, interval);

private void EvictExpiredItems(object state)
{
    lock (_globalStaticLock)
    {
        DoStuff();
    }
}
```

However my concern is - because timer-callbacks are executed on thread-pool threads (?), and I'm actually blocking the thread, this can lead to thread starvation (for example, in an ASP.NET app).

Is this a valid concern?

My solution is to make the timer-callback `async` and use `SempahoreSlim` instead of a `lock`.

```
private async void EvictExpiredItems(object state)
{
    await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(); //static semaphore var
    try
    {
        DoStuff();
    }
    finally
    {
         _semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}
```

Is this a valid concern and is this a valid solution?

Comment: Maybe it's due to simplification but that method seems to not use its parameter. If that's actually the case, then I would ask if it is necessary to actually wait? Couldn't you just skip (return) if the method is already in execution?

Comment: For the async version: I'd make it `async Task`, not `async void`. But here also: couldn't you just probe and return or execute?

Comment: @Fildor the parameters simply comes from `TimerCallback` signature. No, I cannot skip the method, it's instance-based and should run eventually. My problem is - if the app has multiple instances (like, a thousand) I need a lock to throttle CPU load, it's a non-critical task that's ok to execute sequentially in case of clashing. However, my concern is - locking in a thread-pool thread seems like a very bad idea. Profiling an app confirms there' a lot of waiting

Comment: @Fildor yep, `async void` is OK-ish for timer events (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/38917818/56621) but that's not the question. The question is - should I avoid locks in thread-ppol threads in general?

Comment: "that's ok to execute sequentially in case of clashing" => batch calls. While the method is still executing, write call "requests" to a queue (eliminating dupes). If the method is not already running, add the current request to the queue, then consume the whole queue.

Comment: "should I avoid locks in thread-ppol threads in general?" - in general: don't think so. _If it's likely to accumulate probability of congestion/collisions or even deadlocks_: yes. So, in this case, I'd say yes.

Comment: A completely different approach would be to change the eviction process, so the problem doesn't arise in the first place, but that's dodging this question,  I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the `lock` in the timer's callback you are risking thread pool starvation. The [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) component invokes to callback on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool), so in case the `DoStuff` takes a lot of time, and during this time the callback invocations are more than the threads available in the `ThreadPool`, the `ThreadPool` will become saturated. This means that new requests for work will not be satisfied immediately, and instead they'll satisfied only when a thread becomes available. The `ThreadPool` has an algorithm that creates or destroys threads when it has too few or too many, so a saturation incident rarely results in a deadlock, but the performance and responsiveness of your application might take an observable hit. If we are talking about an ASP.NET application, the scalability of your application might be seriously harmed too.

On the contrary using the `await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()` approach can achieve the same goal (prevent overlapping invocations of the `DoStuff`), without causing thread pool starvation. From this aspect the semaphore is better than the `lock`. Both are unlikely to be the optimal solutions for whatever feature you are trying to implement though.