# ThreadPool and Synchronous Execution

Tags: c#, async-await, threadpool, asp.net-core-6.0, background-task

I have a .NET Core application that uses a `ThreadPool`. Each thread in the thread pool executes logic that talks to the database and makes HTTPS calls. The `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessQueue);` does not allow me to enqueue the async function. Is there a problem if I use `.GetResult()` or `.Result` inside the `ProcessQueue()` function? Will it create any deadlock problem or any other issue?

My application does not have any UI or interaction with the user. I expect each item in the thread pool to be long-running, and I want to control how many of these items can run in parallel.

Here is an example implementation of Thread Management class

```
public Boolean EnqueueTask(TKey taskId)
{
    if (null == taskId)
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"TaskID cannot be null");

    if (EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(default(TKey), taskId))
        throw new ArgumentException($"TaskID invalid value for TaskId. Default value for TaskId is passed");

    if (taskDictionary.AddAtomatically(taskId))
    {
        taskAvailableEvent.Set();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessQueue);
        return true;
    }
    else 
        return false;
}

private void ProcessQueue(object? state)
{
    if (this.taskDictionary.GetNextItemAtomatically(out TKey? taskId))
    {
        if (null == taskId)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("A Null TaskId is inserted. TaskId needs to be non-null value");

        T worker = workerFactory.Create();

        try
        {
            worker.Execute(taskId);

            if (!this.taskDictionary.TryRemoveAtomatically(taskId, out _))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("System Failur: Cannot remove item from Task dictionary");
        }
        finally
        {
            worker.Dispose();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        taskAvailableEvent.Reset();
        taskAvailableEvent.Wait(); 
    }
}
```

Here, the `worker.Execute(taskId);` will be performing all the database execution and HTTP calls. But as you can see, I cannot use `await` to call this function, or in other word, this `Execute()` function cannot be `async`.

Comment: A deadlock occurs when each of two threads tries to lock a resource the other has already locked. Neither thread can make any further progress. So, in your case, it depends on your task, whether it meets such conditions or not. Besides, from your description, the task will be performing all the database execution, in this scenario, please remember to avoid the database deadlock or concurrency conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Let's say each task processes a unique client request. So, no two threads will process the same client or the same request. The processing involves REST API calling and DB access. So, the threads will access the database concurrently, but on different rows, and also access REST API concurrently, but with different parameters. I am confident, nothing for the deadline from a logic point of view. I worried about the .net core 6 part.

Comment: "Let's say each task processes a unique client request." In this case the problem most likely is in the database or API, instead of Threadpool. Pay more attention to avoid the database deadlock or concurrency conflicts.

Comment: What is the type of the `taskDictionary`? The `GetNextItemAtomatically` etc methods don't look familiar.

Answer (score 0):

> The ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessQueue); does not allow me to enqueue the async function.

No, but `Task.Run` does. I recommend using `Task.Run`.

> Is there a problem if I use .GetResult() or .Result inside the ProcessQueue() function? Will it create any deadlock problem or any other issue? ... I want to control how many of these items can run in parallel.

Possibly. Blocking thread pool threads can cause thread exhaustion. If their blocking is waiting for something else that needs a free thread pool thread to complete, then deadlock is a possibility.

> I want to control how many of these items can run in parallel.

There are various ways to do this, but one of the simplest is to use `SemaphoreSlim`. Alternatively, you can consider using TPL Dataflow, which has concurrency control built-in.

Comment: *"No, but `Task.Run` does."* -- Why not schedule an `async void` callback with the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`? My guess is that the OP most likely is going to fire-and-forget the `Task.Run`, which is arguably worse than [fire-and-crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659603/async-void-asp-net-and-count-of-outstanding-operations/17660475#17660475 "Async Void, ASP.Net, and Count of Outstanding Operations").

Comment: I agree fire-and-crash is better than fire-and-forget. Neither is best; this may be a place where structured concurrency can be used.