# Unit testing async void event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, events, async-await

I have implemented the MVP (MVC) pattern in c# winforms.

My View and Presenter are as follows (without all the MVP glue):

```
public interface IExampleView
{
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> SaveClicked;
    string Message {get; set; }
}

public partial class ExampleView : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SaveClicked;

    string Message { 
        get { return txtMessage.Text; } 
        set { txtMessage.Text = value; } 
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SaveClicked != null) SaveClicked.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}

public class ExamplePresenter
{
    public void OnLoad()
    {
        View.SaveClicked += View_SaveClicked;
    }

    private async void View_SaveClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => 
        {
            // Do save
        });

        View.Message = "Saved!"
    }
```

I am using MSTest for unit testing, along with NSubstitute for mocking. I want to simulate a button click in the view to test the controller's `View_SaveClicked` code as have the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WhenSaveButtonClicked_ThenSaveMessageShouldBeShown()
{
    // Arrange

    // Act
    View.SaveClicked += Raise.EventWith(new object(), new EventArgs());

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Saved!", View.Message);
}
```

I am able to raise the `View.SaveClicked` successfully using NSubstitute's `Raise.EventWith`.  However, the problem is that code immediately proceeds to the `Assert` before the Presenter has had time to save the message and the `Assert` fails.

I understand why this is happening and have managed to get around it by adding a `Thread.Sleep(500)` before the `Assert`, but this is less than ideal. I could also update my view to call a `presenter.Save()` method instead, but I would like the View to be Presenter agnostic as much as possible.

So would like to know I can improve the unit test to either wait for the `async View_SaveClicked` to finish or change the View/Presenter code to allow them to be unit tested easier in this situation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [Await an async void method call for unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205590/await-a-async-void-method-call-for-unit-testing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are just concerned about unit testing, then you can use a custom `SynchronizationContext`, which allows you to detect the completion of `async void` methods.

You can use my [`AsyncContext` type](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Context) for this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WhenSaveButtonClicked_ThenSaveMessageShouldBeShown()
{
  // Arrange

  AsyncContext.Run(() =>
  {
    // Act
    View.SaveClicked += Raise.EventWith(new object(), new EventArgs());
  });

  // Assert
  Assert.AreEqual("Saved!", View.Message);
}
```

However, it's best to [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) in your own code (as I describe in an MSDN article on async best practices). I have a blog post specifically about a few approaches on "[async event handlers](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html)".

One approach is to replace all `EventHandler<T>` events with plain delegates, and call it via `await`:

```
public Func<Object, EventArgs, Task> SaveClicked;
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (SaveClicked != null) await SaveClicked(sender, e);
}
```

This is less pretty if you want a real *event*, though:

```
public delegate Task AsyncEventHandler<T>(object sender, T e);
public event AsyncEventHandler<EventArgs> SaveClicked;
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (SaveClicked != null)
    await Task.WhenAll(
      SaveClicked.GetInvocationList().Cast<AsyncEventHandler<T>>
          .Select(x => x(sender, e)));
}
```

With this approach, any synchronous event handlers would need to return `Task.CompletedTask` at the end of the handler.

Another approach is to extend the `EventArgs` with a "deferral". This is also not pretty, but is more idiomatic for asynchronous event handlers.

Comment: AsyncContext looks promising but requires .NET 4.6 and we are using 4.5 :(

Comment: With the public Func<Object, EventArgs, Task> SaveClicked suggestion, what would the presenter and unit test code look like?

Comment: I have figured it out.

Controller:

View.SaveClicked = View_SaveClicked;

private async Task View_SaveClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

Unit test:

View.SaveClicked(new object(), new EventArgs()).Wait();

Comment: @Langers: No, don't use `Wait`; use `await`. [`AsyncContext` is available for 4.5 if you use the AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx).

Comment: I am not sure about the `AsyncContext.Run` as a solution to this problem. The first (minor) issue is that it blocks the current thread, and the second (more serious) is that it alters the behavior of the `async void` method. For example the method might contain sync-over-async code that is harmless in a context-free environment, but it causes a deadlock in the single-threaded synchronization context used by the `AsyncContext.Run`. I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636648/wait-for-an-async-void-method/77049223#77049223) an alternative approach that might be better.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a some type work being done of the running task, and you need to use something to return a value from the task.

Seems like the Thread.Sleep helps mitigate that, though, might help to add some logic, and get a value from the task.

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

View:

```
await OnGetAll?.Invoke(this, <Event param>);
```

Presenter:

```
_view.OnGetAll += MyFunction;
```

Interfaz View

```
event Func<object, EventArg, Task> OnGetAll;
```

I replace this:

```
event EventHandler? OnGetAll
```