# Async handler clashing with non-async subscription

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I need to subscribe for updates from 3rd party system using provided *async-unfriendly* library ( they will not support async in the near future). The simplified method for subscription expects delegate `Action<float> onTemperatureChange`:

```
// Third party library
class WeatherServer
{
    // I cannot change signature of this method (it is third party)
    void SubscribeTemperature(Action<float> onTemperatureChange);
}
```

I can easily work with such API using synchronous method:

```
void onTemperatureChange(float newTemperature)
{
    // Synchronous temperature handling
}

weatherServer.SubscribeTemperature(onTemperatureChange);
```

What is the recommended approach if I need to have asynchronous temperature handler like this:

```
async Task onTemperatureChangeAsync(float newTemperature)
{
    var feelsLikeTemperature = await anotherLibrary1.GetFeelsLikeTemperature(newTemperature);   
    await  anotherLibrary1.WriteTemperature(feelsLikeTemperature);   
}
```

Please note that above example is heavily simplified and internal handler logic is complex logic full of awaited async methods.

Considering I cannot change class `WeatherServer` and I have to live with subscription via `Action<float> onTemperatureChange`, I have explored following options:

1. Change handler return type to async void `async void onTemperatureChangeAsync(float newTemperature)`, but it complicates unit testing and exceptions:

   ```
   // async void
   async void onTemperatureChangeAsync(float newTemperature)
   {
       // asynchronous temperature handling (for example):
        var feelsLikeTemperature = await anotherLibrary1.GetFeelsLikeTemperature(newTemperature);   
        await anotherLibrary1.WriteTemperature(feelsLikeTemperature);   
   }
   ```
2. Change handler to sync method using `Result` on internal async call,but `.Result()` is a bad practice:

   ```
   void onTemperatureChangeAsync(float newTemperature)
   {
       // Result() is a bad practice
       anotherLibrary.WriteTemperature(newTemperature).Result();    
   }
   ```

Since option 2 using `.Result()` can cause significant issues, I assume that I have to choose with `async void`.

Is there any other way ? I assume that I am not first one, who needs to solve such issue during migration to async world.

Edited: added more awaited calls to `async void` to demonstrate why await is needed inside handler (even if async void cannot be awaited) and removed wrong comment, that async void is completely bad practice as pointed by answers.

Comment: Wrapping handler's code into `Task` with `Wait` or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` (not `.Result`, which is **truly bad practice**) has no benefits. You'll be able to put `await`s inside it, but handler will still wait for its completion synchroniously. `async void` is not *bad* practice, it's just often used thoughtlessly where not supposed to be used. But event handlers (or delegates) is one of not so much cases, when it is applicable.

Comment: I mean, it is normally to make some Button.Click event handler as `async void`. But when you make `async void` connection to database followed by reading something with it - here comes a trouble.

Comment: Just ensure that your target object can handle potential concurrent incoming data/calls, and `async void` won't be a problem.

Comment: Related: [Unit testing async void event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857716/unit-testing-async-void-event-handler).

Answer (score 0):

`async void` is the way to go and it is the recommended solution for handlers. Refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void

Assuming that `WeatherServer` does not depend on subscriber's handler internal logic at all. In other words, that `WeatherServer` use *fire and forget* logic. Not relying on handler(s) finish their internal processing, before firing again. Additional info from @Stephen Cleary: "async void does allow overlapping event handlers, though (i.e., the next event can be triggered before the first event handler completes). If this is a problem, you can have the handler just insert the value into a queue (e.g., Channel), and then have a queue processor that dequeues the values one at a time and (asynchronously) processes each one."

Handler `async void onTemperatureChangeAsync(float newTemperature)` must follow some guidelines:

- Should not raise/propagate exceptions. Exceptions thrown by async void methods cannot be caught by the methods that started the async void work. In other words, it is a good idea to handle any exception within handler `onTemperatureChangeAsync`.
- Must be able to handle potential concurrent incoming calls from  `WeatherServer`
- Async void methods are difficult to test, so it might be good idea to implement proper `async Task onTemperatureChangeAsync(float newTemperature)` method which will be unit tested and `async void wrapper` to be used as handler

```
// Proper Async method (used for unit testing)
async Task onTemperatureChangeAsync(float newTemperature)
{
    try
    {
        var feelsLikeTemperature = await anotherLibrary1.GetFeelsLikeTemperature(newTemperature);   
        await anotherLibrary1.WriteTemperature(feelsLikeTemperature);   
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        log.Error("Handler failed");
    }
}

// Handler
async void onTemperatureChangeVoidAsync(float newTemperature)
{
   await onTemperatureChangeAsync(newTemperature)
}


weatherServer.SubscribeTemperature(onTemperatureChangeVoidAsync);
```

I have compiled the answer based on @Aditive hints/comments and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void

Any further hints welcomed. I will try to add useful hints to this answer.

If  `WeatherServer` should wait for handler before continuing or should even catch exceptions thrown by handler, the above recommendation to use `async void` does not apply, but it would be the edge case and it might be even a gap in the design…

Comment: Yes, in this case `async void` is acceptable, since it is an event handler. Note that `async void` does allow overlapping event handlers, though (i.e., the next event can be triggered before the first event handler completes). If this is a problem, you can have the handler just insert the value into a queue (e.g., `Channel<float>`), and then have a queue processor that dequeues the values one at a time and (asynchronously) processes each one.