# Content.ReadAsAsync always gives null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am facing issue in reading consents using `Content.ReadAsAsync`. 
Have a look at my code.

```
private HttpResponseMessage _responseMessage;
_responseMessage = UnitTestHelper.Get(string.Format("api/StudentController/Get/?StartDate={0}&EndDate={1}", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now));
Assert.IsTrue(_responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode);
Assert.IsTrue(_responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<StudentModel>>().Result.Count > 0);
var auditData = _responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
_responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<StudentModel>>().Result;
```

**Outcome of above code:**

- It successfully make post call, gets the result back.
- Result.Count shows 1.
- ReadAsStringAsync shows data in the following format.

  ```
  [{\"User\":\"Test\",\"Location\":\"MyCountry\",\"Class\":\"Grade1\",\"Time\":\"2016-07-06T07:26:11.183\",\"SchoolName\":\"ABC School System\"}]
  ```
- Last line gives null. I am expecting a list here.

**My Problem.**

The following line of code always shows null. Whereas I am expecting to have list.

```
_responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<StudentModel>>().Result;
```

Why? What is wrong here?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205590/await-a-async-void-method-call-for-unit-testing

Comment: You question is confusing. How can you get access to `Result.Count` if the prefixed object is `null`?

Comment: have a look at question again. updated.

Comment: @immirza, `ReadAsStringAsync` format is not JSON per say but rather a string that has been Json-encoded, hence the slashes. That would mean that what ever is returning the data is passing a JSON formatted string and not JSON. You understand? Show the action that maps to the url you are calling.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're calling `_responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<StudentModel>>()` twice. You should store the result in some variable and then work with it

```
var result = _responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<StudentModel>>().Result;
Assert.IsTrue(result.Count > 0);
//do whatever needed with result
```

Also you'd better utilize `async/await` instead of calling `.Result`

---

To be more specific `ReadAsAsync<T>` uses internaly `HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync` which caches memory stream and once it is read `Position` stays at the end of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update NewtonSoft.json.dll to the latest. This should work.

Comment: What is the latest ? It change between days/month etc... Please [edit] your answer to add details