# Moq Raise for an async event listener

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, moq

in WPF, I am trying to use moq to raise an event that has an async listener hooked to it:

My code:

```
 public class Provider
    {
       private IService _service
       public Provider(IService service)
       {
         _service = service;
         _service.OnResultsChanged += ChangeResults;
       }

       private async void ChangeResults(List resultsAdded)
       {
         await Task.Run(() => HasResults = true;)
       }
   }
```

For simplification, i've set hasresults to true, but I am really adding items to a list and as this operation could take a while, I am doing it in a new task. In my test, the following fails, as it doesn't wait for the DoSomething execution:

My test:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
//Arrange
var serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
var systemUnderTest = new Provider(serviceMock .Object);

//Act
serviceMock.Raise(mock => mock.OnResultsChanged += null);

//Assert
Assert.IsTrue(systemUnderTest.HasResults);
}
```

is it possible to tell mock.raise to await the execution of my event listener?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Await a Async Void method call for unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205590/await-a-async-void-method-call-for-unit-testing)

Comment: @Nkosi, The issue that I get is that the await inside ChageResults never gets awaited. Probably in my simplified example this is not obvious, but when the operation inside the await takes a little longer,  the execution is not awaited and the assert fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the test to be async as well and await a delayed task to allow the async event handler to perform its functionality.

The following example uses a delay in the even handler to simulate a potential long running task.

```
public interface IService {
    event EventHandler OnResultsChanged;
}

public class Provider {
    private IService _service;
    public Provider(IService service) {
        _service = service;
        _service.OnResultsChanged += ChangeResults;
    }

    private async void ChangeResults(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        await Task.Delay(200); //<-- simulate delay
        await Task.Run(() => HasResults = true);
    }

    public bool HasResults { get; set; }
}
```

By converting the test to async and waiting for the raised event, the assertion was able to be asserted.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test() {
        //Arrange
        var serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
        var systemUnderTest = new Provider(serviceMock.Object) {
            HasResults = false
        };

        //Act
        serviceMock.Raise(mock => mock.OnResultsChanged += null, EventArgs.Empty);

        await Task.Delay(300); //<--wait

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(systemUnderTest.HasResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This should work, I will still investigate it a bit more when I have some time to see if there is something in Moq that lets me raise and wait, but this will definitely do for now!