# Await a task that was started in another method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, async-await

I need to make sure a task is finished before moving on with the rest of my unit test.

But it is a task that is awaited inside another method (I am unit testing the method.)

I have tried awaiting the task or calling task.Wait() but each time the test does not work.

The actual method looks like this:

```
private async void DoStuff(long idToLookUp)
{
    IOrder order = await orderService.LookUpIdAsync(idToLookUp);   

    OtherStuff = false;
}
```

I am trying to unit test it like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDoStuff()
{
    //+ Arrange
    var lookupTask = Task<IOrderableTest>.Factory.StartNew(() => validOrder);
    orderService.LookUpIdAsync(Arg.Any<long>()).Returns(lookupTask);

    //+ Act
    myViewModel.DoStuff();
    await lookupTask;

    //+ Assert
    myViewModel.OtherStuff.Should().BeFalse();
}
```

The way it fails is very unhelpful.  In   It causes another test to fail with "The agent process was stopped while the test was running."  (From what I can read, that means a background thread threw an exception while the test was running.)

**So I am wondering how I can get my code to wait for that unit test to finish.**

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097066/16241) answer that seems fairly good.   But it is more geared toward the calling of the method.  I am not calling it, I just have the task only.

NOTE: I am targeting .NET 4.0 using the ansyc pack.

Comment: Don't create `async void`s; you can't wait for them.

Comment: @SLaks - Alas, many things require void method signatures.  (Commands are one of them.  I suppose I can have two methods for each of my command calls, but it seems messy.)

Comment: @Vaccano In such cases, you should be extremely careful. Because most of the time that means `async` just won't work with those things. Very rarely is using `async void` the right solution.

Answer (score 6):

You should never have a `void` returning `async` method unless it's going to be an event handler (in which case you have no choice).  When an `async` method is `void` you have no way of knowing when it finishes.

The method should return a `Task` (and not a `Task<T>` if it has no meaningful result, just an indication that it finishes).

Once it returns a `Task` you can `await` it when testing it, or use `Wait`, if that's appropriate.

You're awaiting one of the tasks the method is dependent on, but that doesn't mean it's finished it's own code.  This means your test has introduced a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

This call  `await myViewModel.DoStuff();` returns as soon as the await keyword is hit (well unless it is finished very quickly). Plus as Slaks mentionned you can't await a void return method.

Then you Wait on the `var lookupTask = Task<IOrderableTest>.Factory.StartNew(() => validOrder);`
which doesn't seem to be doing much, except returning an `IOrderableTest` .

Plus I don't think you should do `await lookupTask`, this will again return to the caller, in this case the TestRunner doesn't/might not expect this.

You should use instead `lookupTask.Wait()` (this is a **blocking** call);  And make sure it takes enough time for the `myViewModel.DoStuff();` to be completed as well.

**Summary** :

```
private async Task DoStuff(long idToLookUp)
{
    IOrder order = await orderService.LookUpIdAsync(idToLookUp);   

    OtherStuff = false;
    return;
}
```

....

```
 var task = myViewModel.DoStuff();
 Task.WaitAll(task, lookupTask);
```