# Correct way to rewrite my Utils library with Async/Await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a lot of Utils classes that I use for many different projects, most of them are static and made out of static methods that usually don't even call each others.

My intention is to take advantages from the new async/await features but without rewriting everything, so my question is: can I just add a new method for each existing method named MethodAsync with the Task.Run(() => MethodName)?

example:

```
//old code that will not be removed
static void DoSomething()
{ ... }

//new code that will be added
static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
   //not really sure if Im supposed to use await/async here.
   //isn't Task awaitable even without async??
   return await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
}
```

Basically in the old code I just had a normal sync method while in the new one I have an async method that could even run in another thread if the CLR see it as a CPU-bound method.

If I correctly understand, every  asyncronous method contains by definition an await to an awaitable object which is a Task or another asyncronous method.

that means that whenever I can use an async .NET method, I should await it and mark my caller method as async.

But, every other method that do not call any async method but could take some time to complete should be called with a Task.Run call.

right?

**EDIT**

so I have read all the posted links, the best practices on msdn and a few blog posts but I still need a complete routine to follow when coding with the new async/await feature.
this is what I get so far:

1) every .NET method that has an async alternative should use the async alternative. (As far as I know the .NET async methods already exists ONLY for methods that can be async).

2) every method that use async methods should be made async too.

3) every method that do not use async methods (cause there aren't available) but still takes some cpu-time to execute should be made async by wrapping them using Task.Run (I understand that in this case it should be the client to use Task.Run if they want but since im only adding these wrappers for methods that takes more than 50ms to execute and there will be still available the non-async version of the method, I still don't see why I shouldn't place this wrapper in the library).

4) every method that takes non-cpu-time cause it's waiting for other sources (like internet, database, events, etc...) should use TaskFactory.FromAsync or TaskCompletionSource.

5) System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke(method1, method2, etc...) is now deprecated. From what I read Task.Run already run concurrent threads if the CLR thinks that concurrency is required. So it seems that Task.Run already uses Parallel.Invoke when needed.

Comment: Don't do that at all.  Do not create `*Async()` methods unless they're actually asynchronous; never call `Task.Run()` in a library.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx)

Comment: Where does it say that `Parallel.Invoke` is deprecated? And where is it stated that `Task.Run` uses `Parallel.Invoke`? I thought it resulted in the use of the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: Your point (3) is incorrect; `Task.Run` should only be used to *call* CPU-bound methods from a UI thread. The reason you don't want to put wrappers in the library is because you want to be able to use (1) everywhere. I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) that goes into more detail. Also, (5) is incorrect; `Parallel.Invoke` offers many more options than `Task.Run`, and the details are different for parallel `Task`s (a la `Invoke`) vs. asynchronous `Task`s (a la `Task.Run`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was finally able to find good resources that cleared all my doubts:

the first one is "The Task-based Asynchronous Pattern" available at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957
This document explains the async/await feature, how/when to use it, it contains many practical examples and a few of very usefull static methods that im now using on every project!

The second one is "The zen of async: Best practices for best performance" available at http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T
which is a complete overview of the async feature, with some coverage of the Parallel features and it also explains why it should never be the library that use Task.Run() method but it should be a consumer choice instead.

So in the end I was really confusing multithreading with asynchronous code and I couldn't grasp the advantages of async code because I was just looking at 1 single method at the time while the real benefits of async code can only be seen if the entire project (or at least a consistent portion of it) is written following the async pattern.
For example in asp.net, if there isn't any blocking code (everything written in a async fashion way), then a thread can serve another client while yours is awaiting an async operation, improving scalability, while in a xaml application a thread that launch an async operation can immediately go back to supporting your UI instead of just waiting that operation to be over, improving responsiveness.

Comment: +1 for doing some real discovery, I love the talk "The zen of async". The real advantages of async/await come when you are waiting for some external resource, e.g. The file system, a database, some network traffic, a system mutex etc. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18015586/921321) for some brief guidance of when to use `Task.Run`

Answer (score 5):

This has been discussed in [*Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) The part of this article that I thought highlighted why this is bad design is below:

> Consider, for example, a simple method like `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Add(TKey,TValue)`.  This is a really fast method, right?  Typically, yes, but remember how dictionary works: it needs to hash the key in order to find the right bucket to put it into, and it needs to check for equality of the key with other entries already in the bucket.  Those hashing and equality checks can result in calls to user code, and who knows what those operations do or how long they take.  Should every method on dictionary have an asynchronous wrapper exposed? That’s obviously an extreme example, but there are simpler ones, like Regex.  The complexity of the regular expression pattern provided to Regex as well as the nature and size of the input string can have significant impact on the running time of matching with Regex, so much so that Regex now supports optional timeouts… should every method on Regex have an asynchronous equivalent?  I really hope not.

Obviously I advise you to read the entire article too, but I hope the above highlights a great reason why exposing `*Async()` methods should not wrap synchronous ones in a library.

I hope this helps.

Comment: MoonKnight.   FYI link to full article is broken.