# "async Task" vs "return Task.Run"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to async/await c# model and trying to understand if these two options are essentially the same thing:

```
public Task LongRunningMethod()
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await DoStuff();
    });
}

//then call it
await LongRunningMethod();
```

and this

```
public async Task LongRunningMethod()
{
    await DoStuff();
}

//then call it
await LongRunningMethod();
```

I'm thinking the 1st way will use up an extra thread from the pool... And it also wraps a Task into an extra Task. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Related: [await task.run vs await c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739403/await-task-run-vs-await-c-sharp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Task.Run` will queue its delegate to the thread pool. This causes two important things:

1. Any code in `DoStuff` before the first asynchronous `await` will run on a thread pool thread, instead of [on the calling thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).
2. The code in `DoStuff` will run in a thread pool context, instead of [using whatever context was current from the calling thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

*Most* of the time, doing asynchronous work in `Task.Run` is a mistake. But it is sometimes useful, say if `DoStuff` does some heavy computational work before it acts asynchronously, then `Task.Run` could be used to move that work off of a UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

They are *very similar*, but there is a chance that `DoStuff` could complete synchronously; if that happens, your second (`await` only) method would block for however long that takes, where-as the first (`Task.Run`) would always return incomplete to the caller (unwinding their stack and scheduling a continuation), and have the blocking work run on the pool thread.

Both options can be desirable, in different scenarios!

However, there is a third option, which expresses *exactly* the intent of "run the rest somewhere else" **as long as** you don't have a `SyncContext`:

```cs
public async Task LongRunningMethod()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    await DoStuff(); // possibly with .ConfigureAwait(false)
}
```

If there is no `SyncContext`, this is functionally similar to the `Task.Run` version (meaning: it will always return to the caller as incomplete, and run the `DoStuff` starting on the pool), just: without the actual `Task.Run` bits. However, if there *is* a `SyncContext`: it will go back onto the *same* context, which is ... awkward, and unfortunately there is no `ConfigureAwait(false)` for `YieldAwaitable`, so *in that case* you'd have to use `Task.Run` or similar.

Comment: You should call yourself the god of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`.

Comment: @TanveerBadar yield before me!

Comment: If LongRunningMethod is called on the gui thread then DoStuff will also run on the gui thread, not in the thread pool. You'll need a ConfigureAwait to get it into the pool.

Comment: @Sean yes, you're right - if there's a sync context, it will go *back* to the sync context; I'll reflect that (I've gotten so used to living in a world without sync-context; I don't miss them!)

Comment: Why prefer `await Task.Yield` over `await Task.Run(async () =>`? Is it more efficient? Or just because it's more expressive? (assuming it is)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias mostly about expressing intent, although I believe it does shave a few pieces - but not enough to matter in any realistic scenarios (if you're hammering `Yield` that much, you're probably not batching enough)

Answer (score 1):

The method name conveys the reason why it is done like that, "LongRunning". You can pass a creation flag `LongRunning` to `Task.Run()` (which this sample doesn't) and as a pure implementation thread, runtime will allocate a separate thread for that.

Even your second example isn't completely correct, depending on circumstances. If this is a library, then it really should be `await DoStuff().ConfigureAwait(false);`.