# Searching for a Task.Yield equivalent that yields to the thread pool

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

The [`Task.Yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield) method *"creates an awaitable task that asynchronously yields back to the current context when awaited."* I am searching for something similar that should guarantee that any code that follows will run on a `ThreadPool` thread. I know that I could achieve this be enclosing all the following code in a `Task.Run`, but I am searching for an inline solution that doesn't create an inner scope.

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Yield(); // Doesn't do what I want
    // Code that should run on the ThreadPool
}

private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Does what I want, but I am not happy with the added indentation and scope
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        // Code that should run on the ThreadPool
    });
}
```

The best I can think of is to use the `Task.Run` with an empty delegate, and configure the awaiting to **not** capture the synchronization context:

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Probably does what I want, but it looks ugly
    await Task.Run(() => { }).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    // Code that should run on the ThreadPool
}
```

This looks like an obscure line of code, and I am not sure that expresses well enough the intent of being there. I am also not sure if it provides the guarantees I want. Is there any other solution?

<sub>Btw this question is inspired by a Marc Gravell's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433284/async-task-vs-return-task-run/62433462#62433462) to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433284/async-task-vs-return-task-run).</sub>

---

**Update:** I should give a more specific reason about why using the standard `await Task.Run(() =>`  is not ideal in my case. I have some code that should run on the `ThreadPool` or not, depending on some condition. So a `Task.Yield` equivalent would allow me to do this:

```
private bool _executeOnThreadPool;

private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_executeOnThreadPool) await SwitchToTheThreadPool();
    // Code that should run on the ThreadPool or the UI thread
}
```

I can't do the same thing with `Task.Run` without code duplication, or without adding lambdas and indirection.

Comment: `await Task.Delay(0).ConfigureAwait(false);` ? Also I would say that second option is the clearest one.

Comment: @GuruStron AFAIK the `Task.Delay(0)` returns a completed task, so the following code will continue on the UI thread.

Comment: Yep. seems so. Then Task.Delay(1) =)))

Comment: @GuruStron I am not very happy with this either, because it introduces a tiny but unneeded artificial delay.

Comment: You could format your code [like this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyAMABMugKwDcOyAzEagQMIEDeOBbRNyAHEQCwEAxAPZCAFAEoCAXgB8RAJxEAbADoASgFcAdqInSZrdi2yG2AX3EVsZoA) and avoid the indentation >:

Comment: @canton7 this formatting is nifty, thanks. But I am searching for a true inline solution, based on the magical `await` keyword, with no extra scope/closure added to the mix. :-)

Comment: Raymond Chen's blogged about something I'm sure

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why was “SwitchTo” removed from Async CTP / Release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363413/why-was-switchto-removed-from-async-ctp-release/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raymond Chen posted about this in his blog [The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) in the post [C++/WinRT envy: Bringing thread switching tasks to C# (WPF and WinForms edition)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190329-00/?p=102373).

Reproduced here in case the source goes down:

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
> using System.Threading;          // For ThreadPool
> using System.Windows.Forms;      // For Windows Forms
> using System.Windows.Threading;  // For WPF
>
> // For WPF
> struct DispatcherThreadSwitcher : INotifyCompletion
> {
>     internal DispatcherThreadSwitcher(Dispatcher dispatcher) =>
>         this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
>     public DispatcherThreadSwitcher GetAwaiter() => this;
>     public bool IsCompleted => dispatcher.CheckAccess();
>     public void GetResult() { }
>     public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) =>
>         dispatcher.BeginInvoke(continuation);
>     Dispatcher dispatcher;
> }
>
> // For Windows Forms
> struct ControlThreadSwitcher : INotifyCompletion
> {
>     internal ControlThreadSwitcher(Control control) =>
>         this.control = control;
>     public ControlThreadSwitcher GetAwaiter() => this;
>     public bool IsCompleted => !control.InvokeRequired;
>     public void GetResult() { }
>     public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) =>
>         control.BeginInvoke(continuation);
>     Control control;
> }
>
> // For both WPF and Windows Forms
> struct ThreadPoolThreadSwitcher : INotifyCompletion
> {
>     public ThreadPoolThreadSwitcher GetAwaiter() => this;
>     public bool IsCompleted =>
>         SynchronizationContext.Current == null;
>     public void GetResult() { }
>     public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) =>
>         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => continuation());
> }
>
> class ThreadSwitcher
> {
>     // For WPF
>     static public DispatcherThreadSwitcher ResumeForegroundAsync(
>         Dispatcher dispatcher) =>
>         new DispatcherThreadSwitcher(dispatcher);
>
>     // For Windows Forms
>     static public ControlThreadSwitcher ResumeForegroundAsync(
>         Control control) =>
>         new ControlThreadSwitcher(control);
>
>     // For both WPF and Windows Forms
>     static public ThreadPoolThreadSwitcher ResumeBackgroundAsync() =>
>          new ThreadPoolThreadSwitcher();
> }
> ```

This lets you do:

```
await ThreadSwitcher.ResumeBackgroundAsync();
```

---

I'd be wary about actually doing this in a shared codebase however: it's not particularly idiomatic, whereas `Task.Run` is very clear.

Comment: Thaks canton7, this is very helpful! I managed to achieve exactly the behavior I want by making an adaptation to the `ThreadPoolThreadSwitcher`s property `IsCompleted`. This is my version: `public bool IsCompleted => Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread;`

Comment: Yeah, checking the SynchronizationContext did seem a little weird: that indicates any old non-dispatcher thread, rather than a ThreadPool thread specifically.