# Use ConfigureAwait(false) or Task.Run to avoid blocking UI Thread

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-core, async-await

I'm trying to find out which approach is better let's say we have a button, after user clicks it we perform 1. Send a async request using `httpClient`
2. Some heavy synchronous staff like computations and saving data to a database.

Like that:

```
button1.Click += async(sender, e) => 
{
    bool a = await Task.Run(async () => { return await MyTask1();});
}
async Task<bool> MyTask1()
{
    await new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://www.webpage.com");
    DoHeavyStuffFor5minutes();
    return true;
}
```

```
button2.Click += async(sender, e) => 
{
    bool a = await MyTask2();
}
async Task<bool> MyTask2()
{
    await new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://www.webpage.com").ConfigureAwait(false);
    DoHeavyStuffFor5minutes();
}
```

From what i understand `GetAsync` does not block my UI thread because underneath it uses a method which make it runs on different thread perhaps `Task.Run` or any other method that allows that.
But `DoHeavyStuffFor5Minutes` will block my UI because it will get called on the caller `SynchornizationContext`.
So i read that using `ConfigureAwait(false)` will make code after `GetAsync` do not run on the same SynchornizationContext as the caller. My question is, which approach is better first or the second one?

Comment: Why isn't the "heavy stuff on a database" asynchronous?

Comment: edited question to avoid this kind of confusion

Comment: @whd The point still stands.  If the operation is spending time saving stuff to the DB, why are you not doing that asynchronously?

Comment: @Servy let say it is a method from a library which does not offer async methods. But in this case it is still valid question what is better `await SomeAsynMethod(); Task.Run(() => { SomeHeavyMethod();};` or `await SomeAsyncMethod().ConfigureAwait(false); SomeHeavyMethod();`

Comment: The first approach is better IMHO. You can read my arguments in favor of `Task.Run` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739403/await-task-run-vs-await/58306020#58306020).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to execute `HttpClient.GetAsync` on a background thread using `Task.Run` since the HTTP request is truly asynchronous by nature so in this case your second approach is better that the first one.

When the `Task` returned by `GetAsync` has eventually finished, the remainder or `MyTask2()` will be executed on a thread pool thread assuming you opt out of capturing the context by calling `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Note however that `ConfigureAwait(false)` does not guarantee that the callback or remainer won't be run in the original context in all cases.

From Stephen Toub's [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/):

> **Does ConfigureAwait(false) guarantee the callback won’t be run in the original context?**

*"No. It guarantees it won’t be queued back to the original contex...but that doesn’t mean the code after an `await task.ConfigureAwait(false)` won’t still run in the original context. That’s because awaits on already-completed awaitables just keep running past the `await` synchronously rather than forcing anything to be queued back. So, if you `await` a task that’s already completed by the time it’s awaited, regardless of whether you used `ConfigureAwait(false)`, the code immediately after this will continue to execute on the current thread in whatever context is still current."*

So you might want to off-load `DoHeavysTuffFor5minutes`, which I assume is a CPU-bound and potentially long-running operation, to a background thread using `Task.Run` to be on the safe side. At least in the general case.

Also note that a method that is named *Async and returns a `Task` or `Task<T>` might still block the calling thread depending on its implementation. In general, this may be a reason to use your first approach of a calling both methods on a background thread in order to avoid blocking the UI thread. If you however use well-implemented APIs, such as `HttpClient`, this isn't an issue though.

Comment: "At least in the general case." - yes. In particular, `HttpClient` on some mobile platforms may return (cached) results synchronously.