# In Blazor what is the difference between `await Task.Run(StateHasChanged)` and `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've recently inherited a Blazor Webassembly application, however have minimal experience with dotnet or Blazor.

Some of the components use `await Task.Run(StateHasChanged)` rather than `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` and I'm wondering if this is intentional.

I ask as `await Task.Run(StateHasChanged);` gives me the following exception when attempting to render the component using bUnit:

> System.InvalidOperationException The current thread is not associated
> with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the
> Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.

Changing this to `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` allows the component to be rendered in bUnit. However, as far as I can tell, the component functions identically when using the application for either `await Task.Run(StateHasChanged)` or `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`.

What is the difference between these two approaches to invoking `StateHasChanged`?

Comment: This post explains the difference in general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739403/await-task-run-vs-await/ I'd imagine that the StateHasChanged stuff follows the same explaination "Task.Run may post the operation to be processed at a different thread. That's the only difference."

Comment: a DevOps engineer inheriting a Blazor project. All the best to you!

Comment: InvokeAsync needs to be called when UI refresh are needed from actions on a non-UI event, this will allow to send the StateHasChanged to the UI Thread. When an event is UI based, this is not needed. Task.Run creates a new context, it is not on the UI Thread. (Asp.net Core Doc on using StateHasChanged)   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-6.0#when-to-call-statehaschanged

Comment: By threads, I am not sure I use the right term, its more like context, as with Blazor Wasm, it is not clear it can handle multiple threads yet. Webassembly seems to support it, but not all browser do, or did not a long time ago. So using a Task.Run can and will block the main thread if multiple threads are not yet supported.

Comment: @Shuryno: that 1st comment would have made an answer...   And Task.Run() won't block, it just gets executed on the main Thread.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, first link explains Task.Run, but not InvokeAsync... It provide a nice info though. As for running a Task on main thread, If you run a long task expecting it to run in parallel, but in fact runs on your main thread, what are the effects of it?

Comment: It would block the UI. Not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as far as I can tell, the component functions identically ...

That is correct. `Task.Run(job)` will run the job on the ThreadPool. In WebAssembly however there are no extra threads and the main (only) thread will have to run this job sooner or later.

In Blazor Server you do have Threads. `Task.Run()` will work there, but `StateHasChanged()` *has to* run on the main Thread. That means that

```
 await Task.Run(StateHasChanged)   // bug!  Don't do this.
```

definitely is a bug, everywhere. It just goes unnoticed on WebAssembly for the time being. Until the day that Blazor Wasm also gets threads, then it will throw.

So bUnit is right, fix your code.

Do note that in 'normal' lifecycle events (like OnInitialized[Async], OnClick, OnSubmit etc) you don't have to use `InvokeAsync()` at all.
I normally use just

```
  StateHasChanged();
```

and in in external events (eg a Timer) or Threaded code (on the Server)

```
  await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
```

Comment: I think the explanation for him getting that error now and the person who develop didn't might be because the browser @Sam Carswell is using supports Wasm multi-thread and it was develop on a browser that didn't? Can't see any other reason it was left there.

Comment: No, ther error is when running in bUnit and bUnit always runs server-side, hence the error. Blazor doesn't support Wasm Threads in any Browser (yet), afaik.

Comment: Oh, ok, yeah I missed that bUnit reference. Good point! :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks for the detailed answer. I have discovered there is a slight difference between the two approaches (not sure if it's intentional or a bug), but I've explained the differing outcomes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70193854/blazor-statehaschanged-and-child-parameters-await-task-runstatehaschanged)