# How to assign Task.Run(await some async function that returns byte[]) to a variable

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a function in c#, call it

```
public async Task<byte[]> PrintLetter(int Id)    
{
    some code here
    return byte[2125];
}
```

I was calling it like this: (not sure what the point of the _ is)

```
 _ = Task.Run(async () => await PrintLetter(cid));
```

And it was running the print job and working fine.
But now I want to assign this `PrintLetter()` to a variable so I can pass along this `byte[]` and not just print to printer.

So I wanted to do this:

```
var files =  await PrintLetter(cid);
return Ok(File(files, "application/pdf", "Letter.pdf"));
```

But I'm nervous to blindly remove the `Task.Run` here.
Any advice

Comment: Why even use task run?

Comment: It was there before my days and running hundreds of thousands of printing.  nervous to remove it

Comment: Your change would mean that the caller would not return until after your `PrintLetter` method completed.  With your original code, it would return immediately since you are not awaiting the `Task.Run`.

Comment: Since you are inside a HttpRequest there is no need to a `Task.Run()` - hence you are already in a new thread. So just do `var files =  await PrintLetter(cid);` as you want to do. You webapp will perform better, not worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just `await` the result of the existing `Task.Run` invocation:

```
byte[] bytes =  await Task.Run(async () => await PrintLetter(cid));
```

In this case the async/await can be safely [elided](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) from the lambda. The behavior of the code below is identical:

```
byte[] bytes =  await Task.Run(() => PrintLetter(cid));
```

Removing the `Task.Run` is not a no-op though. It might be OK, or it might not. You can check out this question for guidance: [await Task.Run vs await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739403/await-task-run-vs-await)

Answer (score 1):

> _ = Task.Run(async () => await PrintLetter(cid));

So, what this is actually doing is a form of fire-and-forget:

1. The `Task.Run` ensures that `PrintLetter` runs outside of the ASP.NET request context. (I'm assuming this is ASP.NET pre-Core).
2. The `_ =` discards the task.

So this will execute `PrintLetter` in a separate thread and not wait for it to complete before returning to the client.

The problem is that fire-and-forget is dangerous. This was never a good solution to begin with. Fortunately, the new requirements (passing back the byte array) means that the fire-and-forget should be removed anyway. This just leaves this:

```
var files =  await PrintLetter(cid);
return Ok(File(files, "application/pdf", "Letter.pdf"));
```