# What's The Actual Difference Between await XXAsync() And await Task.Run(()=>{XX() }

Tags: c#, async-await

By using `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` we can convert synchronous actions to tasks, so that we can use `await`, like this:

```
await Task.Run(() => { SomeMethod(); }
```

In the meantime, many methods themselves have asynchronous implements, so it is recommended to directly use

```
await SomeMethodAsync();
```

But what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When correctly use Task.Run and when just async-await](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013523/when-correctly-use-task-run-and-when-just-async-await)

Comment: The difference is that the first one will be executed in a context you control and the second one will be executed in a context defined by the implementation, which can be anything (simple task, pipeline, ...)

Answer (score 2):

`SomeMethodAsync` is probably a method that does IO work and [IO work does not require a thread to work](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). So `SomeMethodAsync` does not cause a thread from the thread-pool to just sit and wait for it to complete. Thread-pool threads are important resources in server application such as ASP.NET applications. In such applications, each request is serviced by a thread-pool thread and thus the number of active requests can be increased by saving such threads.

`await Task.Run(() => { SomeMethod(); }` uses a thread-pool thread to execute the `SomeMethod` method. If the `SomeMethod` does IO work, then you just used a thread-pool thread unnecessarily.

Comment: Please don't feed the dups. We've all linked to Stephen Cleary's blog post enough times... People really should be finding it on their first click by now.

Comment: If you have a look in the c# reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx you will see that the exemple SomeMethodAsync just wrap a task in a sub. And nothing force task to use a thread-pool. That's just the default behavior... You answer is not wront but it isn't really right either.

Comment: @Aron, although the question you referenced is related, I think it is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @MarcoGuignard, if you use `Task.Run` a thread pool thread will be used. I am not sure I understand your point.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I refuse to believe there is no canonical answer. If there is not, I would like to nominate Stephen Cleary to write one. Perhaps by copy pasta his own blog....

Comment: @YacoubMassad His point is that `Task.Run` is implemented by a thread pool thread under the ".net Framework". There is no guarantee that going forward .net core will use a thread pool thread, nor any other implementation (such as mono) use a thread pool thread. Nor is there any requirement in the specification for Microsoft to use the same implementation in future...Nor does it use a Threadpool thread if you set the LongRunning flag...

Comment: @Aron, the documentation of `Task.Run` says `Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a Task object that represents that work.`

Comment: @YacoubMassad Task use a Taskscheduler object to control the handling. You could override it to make the start execute on the UI thread, a queue on only secondary thread or whatever you want. Tasks are a high-concept which use threadpool "by default" but task are more than that.

Comment: @MarcoGuignard, right. But this is not the point of the question. OP is using the simplest override of `Task.Run` and is asking about calling a natively `async` method vs running a synchronous method via `Task.Run`.