# You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

From the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx),

> You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a background thread.

My question is, are there any other options? If I want to use `await` keyword I must return Task and so I must use `Task.Run`

```
public static Task<int> LongProcess()
{
    return Task.Run<int>(() =>
    {
        //Long running 
        return 5;
    });
}

public async static void CallProcess()
{
    int a = await LongProcess();
}
```

Isn't above code only option to use await? If not, could you please show other options? If I don't use Task.Run, why do I need async/await?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18015586/4767498

Comment: You can effectively only await a Task, which you need to create somehow.  Whether it's Task.Run() or Task.Factory.StartNew(), or new Task() followed by task.Start(), you still need a Task if you want to await it.

Comment: [Asynchrony is not threading](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: You can use `await` on any awaitable objects. E.g. there are many static methods of the `Task` class. See `TaskCompletionSource` class. There are a lot of `*Async` methods in different classes. All of them you can use with `await`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *just* CPU intensive work. More usually you'll use async/await for I/O work that would otherwise lock the thread while waiting for a file system, database, or network operation to complete.