# How to delay excuting the code inside Promise?

Tags: javascript

My code:

```js
class MyPromise extends Promise {
  constructor(func) {
    super(func);
  }
  SomePromiseExtensionMethod() {
    // do stuff...
  }
}

let test = async function() {
  let promise = new MyPromise(function (resolve) {
    console.log('foo');

    resolve();
  });
  
  console.log('start printing:');
  
  await promise;
};

test();
```

I'm leaning `Promise` and want to create a class which derived from `Promise` class.

My question: Is there a way to delay printing `foo` until I call `await promise`?

**UPDATE:**

I want to create this class because I want to run another methods while the object is a `Promise`. (Just like: `mypromise.SomePromiseExtensionMethod()`).

**UPDATE 2:** My real project:

```js
    let Task = (function () {
        let __data = {};

        __data.Run = function (...args) {
            if (args.length) {
                let func = args[0];

                return new Task(func);
            }
        };
        
        class Task extends Promise {
            constructor(action) {
                super(action);
            }
            static set Run(value) {
                return __data.Run;
            }
            static get Run() {
                return (...args) => __data.Run.call(this, ...args);
            }
        }
        return Task;
    }());
    
    let test = async () => {
      let task = Task.Run(r => r(console.log('foo')));
      
      console.log('start printing');
      
      await task;
    };
    
    test();
```

Comment: You really don't want to be extending `Promise`. That's not the way to make use of them.

Comment: *"I want to create a class which derived from Promise class.*" - hint: one never needs to do that.

Comment: Actually even in this synchronous Promise implementation, foo is a result of your call to promise, but doesn't happen before it. However, I believe that you are talking something differently.  You can put the resolve invocation in a timeout callback, e.g., setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);

Comment: @Bergi I have a reason to do that and I just mention it in the update.

Comment: Why dont you simply call a function (that returns a promise and does some console ouput)?

Comment: @Yeah Just curious, with what methods are you extending your promises?

Comment: @Bergi I've another update for your question. It looks like `weird` at this time :)

Comment: @Yeah I'm sorry to say, but your `Task.Run` method doesn't really make much sense, and even less as a static method of a promise subclass. `const taskRun = (...args) => args.length ? new Promise(args[0]) : Promise.reject()` would probably do the same job.

Comment: @Bergi Yes. You're right. I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18015586/7739271) to to create it. I'm sorry but I come from c# background and want to make some js syntax become friendly with c#'s. There is a js plugin, like `linqjs`, so, why not have `Task.js`? `List.js` or `dotnet.js` for future? That's my dream :)

Comment: @Yeah Please don't. Keep the C# where it belongs, and learn the JS idioms. `Task.Run` seems to deal with threads, which we don't have. The rule is not to do heavy CPU-bound work on the client - and if you really needed to, you'd use a web worker.

Comment: @Bergi Uhm. It's very hard while we're working with single-thread (although there is still a way to [delay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292942/7739271) a thread forever). So many things need to implement but js has only 1 object `Promise` for all. Maybe it's better in ES7+, I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to delay printing `foo` until I call `await promise`?

Yes, this is known as "lazy" promises. Notice that `await` is just sugar for calling the `then` method, so we can do this by overwriting the `then` method and only then run the executor callback:

```
class MyPromise extends Promise {
  constructor(func) {
    let run;
    super((resolve, reject) => {
      run = () => func(resolve, reject);
    });
    this.run = run;
  }
  then(onfulfilled, onrejected) {
    const run = this.run;
    if (run) {
      this.run = null;
      run();
    }
    return super.then(onfulfilled, onrejected);
  }
}

(async function test() {
  let promise = new MyPromise(function (resolve) {
    console.log('foo');
    resolve();
  });

  console.log('start printing:');

  await promise;
}());
```

Please use this only for the learning exercise, I wouldn't recommend to use this pattern in an actual project.

Comment: Although it works like that in my Firefox, I cannot find confirmation of "Notice that await is just sugar for calling the then method" in the es spec. Moreover, it seems to say exactly the opposite: overriding of then must not affect await operator.

Comment: Thank you! I will remember it.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Where does it say that? `await` will `resolve` the value to a promise, which follows the standard A+ procedure and calls `then`.

Comment: Here is [how await works](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#abstract-ops-async-function-await) and [how then works](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-promise.prototype.then). They both perform `PerformPromiseThen` operation separately, so they are independent.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Step 3 of *AsyncFunctionAwait* is the one that will call `value.then(…)` if you trace it down. Yes, this leads to *PerformPromiseThen* being called twice.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko, you can feed `await` any value. It will wrap it into a promise, which ultimately (for promise values) will result in `then` being called according to the resolution process of promises.

Comment: @Bergi I do not see anything about calling `then` method in step 3. Can you please link the end of the trace where it is written?

Comment: @SergeSeredenko *Promise Resolve Function* Step 8 and *PromiseResolveThenableJob* will do it. In short, `await x` is equivalent to `Promise.resolve(x).then(resumeWithValue, resumeWithException)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with `then`:

```js
class MyPromise extends Promise {
  constructor(func) {
    super(func);
  }
}

let test = async () => {
  let promise = new MyPromise(function (resolve) {
    resolve();
  }).then(_ => console.log('foo'));
  
  console.log('start printing:');
  
  await promise;
};

test();
```

NB: It is a bad idea to extend the Promise object.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the downvoter but can you explain me why it's a bad idea? Also, I have an update in the question. You can check again. Thank you!

Comment: This delays the printing only for some fixed time, not until `await promise`.

Comment: It delays until after await is encountered. The await itself is resumed like before. But I understood the question to be to have the 'foo' printed later, which is achieved here.