# Implement async "yielding" the proper way

Tags: c#, async-await, task, continuations

Async method runs sync on caller context/thread until its execution path runs into an I/O or similar task which has some waiting involved and then, instead of waiting, it returns to original caller, resuming its continuation later. The question is, what is the preferred way of implementing that "wait" method. How do the File/Network/etc async methods do it?

Lets assume I have a method which will have some waiting involved which is not covered by current IOs out of the box. I do not want to block calling thread and I do not want to force my caller to do a `Task.Run()` to offload me, I want a clean async/await pattern so that my callers can seamlessly integrate my library and I can run on its context until such time I need to yield. Lets for the sake of argument assume that I want to make a new IO lib which is not covered and I need a way to make all the glue that keeps async together.

Do I `Task.Yield` and continue? Do I have to do my own `Task.Run`/`Task.Wait`, etc? Both seem like more of the same abstractions (which brings the question how does `Yield` yield). I am curious, because there is a lot of talk about how async/await continuation works for the consumer and how all IO libs come already prepped, but there is very little about how the actual "breaking" point works and how process makers should implement it. How does the code at the end of a sync path actually release control and how the method operates at that point and after.

Comment: You might want to read [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) and realise it's *async all the way down*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I implement an async I/O bound operation from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985593/how-do-i-implement-an-async-i-o-bound-operation-from-scratch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write your own async method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24953808/11683)

Comment: Would be interesting to know what is that waiting not covered by current IO out of the box. But in general I think you'll have to just use native OS api anyway.

Comment: On Windows I think they use `IOCP` for `IO` bound work (I think). I also think other asynchronous operations use task schedulers backed by the thread pool to efficiently schedule multiple tasks on a single thread.

Comment: Sorry, I should say, on Windows I think they use `IOCP` in conjunction with `OVERLAPPED` `IO`.

Comment: If you think about what an async operation is, what the CPU is doing is asking another device to do something on its behalf. So, for network bound work, the CPU will copy your outbound buffer into some known memory location (usually synchronously) and then ask the NIC to send that data across the wire. The NIC will then notify the CPU when the data has been sent (the CPU doesn't wait). This process specifically would use DMA for the transfer of data from main memory to the NICs internal buffer

Comment: @Evk, a custom hardware chip on an embedded platform. We are playing with potential software solutions for clients now that .net core runs properly on Linux.

Comment: @GSerg, no, not really, this is still "high level" abstraction falling on lower async

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this is just a KoolAid article, whenever a work is being done ther is always a thread, but thats not the issue here, its about custom async signaling. And its not async all the way down, its async all the way down to BCL which covers 99.999% of scenarios. But, if you are 0.001%...

Comment: If you are interested for a `ValueTask`-based example, you could check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69147931/avoiding-allocations-and-maintaining-concurrency-when-wrapping-a-callback-based "Avoiding allocations and maintaining concurrency when wrapping a callback-based API with an async API on a hot path") question .

Comment: No, there isn't a thread. If you read the article, you'd have seen that at the lowest level, it's about handing off to hardware and then letting a later interrupt cause resumption to happen. So if you're in a situation where you're going down to the hardware, you do the same. Only in the odd circumstances that hardware interrupts aren't an option do you need to do different. And that's such an "out there" requirement that you should already be aware that you need to run polling loops, etc. And if you're not directly dealing with hardware, you use your OS's abstraction, that tend to be async.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever lets agree to disagree on this. There is always a thread, be it application thread, kernel level IO polling or a thread responding to an interrupt from device, or for that matter a userland thread transitioning into Ring0 by syscall. No unit of work of any kind can happen without some thread working on it, the article just tries to sensationalize things from a very abstract position. Inside the userland async app, also, it might not be the same thread, but its always A thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're the bottom of the async pile, with no inbuilt async downstream calls to defer to, then: it falls to you. The *simple* way to do this is to allocate a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` (TCS) for some `T`, hook up the async work (that isn't `Task<T>` based) *in whatever way you need to*, stick the TCS somewhere you can get at it later, and hand back the `.Task` from the TCS, to the caller. When the async work completes - possibly via some kind of callback, or whatever is suitable for that API; fetch the TCS from where-ever you stuffed it, and signal completion there, via `TrySetResult` etc.

There are various things to consider, though:

- in many cases, you may want to ensure that you pass `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` to the TCS constructor, if "thread theft" would be a huge concern (otherwise, the `await` steals the thread of whatever calls `.TrySetResult`)
- there are ways of creating and managing `Task[<T>]` instances *without* the additional allocation of a `TaskCompletionSource<T>`, but they're more advanced
- or at the extreme end, if this is high throughput: `ValueTask[<T>]` has a token-based API (via `IValueTaskSource[<T>]`) that allows the same object model to be used many times (as different `ValueTask[<T>]` values), to avoid *any* additional allocations - again, this is an advanced scenario

Comment: Cool, this is actually what I have been looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, now I have to see how all this fares on Linux, but other than hardware specific P/I this looks like a solution... I'll as here if I run into trouble :D

Comment: Btw, you said this is the simple way? What would the complicated way be (I presume with creating and managing Task instances you mentioned)? Can you point me towards some reading material?

Comment: @mmix there are a few APIs you can use; `AsyncMethodBuilder<T>` can do this for you, although how that happens depends on the framework version;  or there's some related tools in the PooledAwait library on nuget - but if allocations "matters* (often it doesn't), then moving to `ValueTask[<T>]` with `IValueTaskSource[<T>]` might be a more practical direction