# Why would this awaited async method return to calling thread before completing?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the following abstract base class that all tasks inherit from.

```
public abstract class ScheduledTaskBase : ITask
{
    private readonly ILogRecorder _logRecorder;
    protected ScheduledTaskBase(ILogRecorder logRecorder)
    {
        _logRecorder = logRecorder;
    }

    protected IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

    public void Run()
    {
        OnRun();
        _logRecorder.LogProcessRunDate(TaskType);
    }
    
    protected abstract ScheduledTask TaskType { get; }
    protected abstract void OnRun();
}
```

This is one of the inheriting class.

```
public class FailedOrderTask : ScheduledTaskBase
{
    protected override ScheduledTask TaskType => ScheduledTask.FailedOrderTask;

    private readonly IService _service;
    public FailedOrderTask(IService service, ILogRecorder logRecorder) : base(logRecorder)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    protected override void OnRun()
    {
        Task.Run(() => { _service.ProcessFailedOrders(); }).Wait();
    }
}
```

Here is the IService's ProcessFailedOrders method.

```
public async Task ProcessFailedOrders()
{
    var orders = await _repository.GetFailedOrders();
    foreach (var order in orders)
        await PlaceOrder(order);
}
```

And the repository's GetFailedOrders method.

```
public async Task<List<Order>> GetFailedOrders()
{
    return await _context.Orders.Where(x => !x.DateOrdered.HasValue).ToListAsync();
}
```

When the task runs and gets into the repository method, it then jumps back out to the ScheduledTaskBase Run method's _logRecorder.LogProcessRunDate line.  This causes a 2nd operation started on this context error.  If I put a breakpoint on the _logRecorder line and then move to the next line - the closing curly brace, it then jumps back to the repository and returns the data to the service.

We have a number of other tasks that are set up the same way where they do something like the following and they work fine.

```
Task.Run(() => SomeClass.Method).Wait()
```

So I can't figure out why this one task always jumps out of the async method only to come back if I don't let the _logRecorder line execute.

Comment: In your `protected override void OnRun()` method, you're not awaiting the async task. I think it's jumping right to the log without waiting for the result. Edit: Would `await _service.ProcessFailedOrders()` work there?

Comment: You wrote `{ _service.ProcessFailedOrders(); }` instead of `=> _service.ProcessFailedOrders` as you mention you use it at other locations in your code. Is that intentional? You might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013523/when-correctly-use-task-run-and-when-just-async-await

Comment: Progman, that was it!  Thank you.  I didn't realize surrounding that call with curly braces would cause the problem.  Removed them and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Both @bigcrazyal and @progman are correct. I'll just elaborate a bit why it happens. This line

```
Task.Run(() => { _service.ProcessFailedOrders(); }).Wait();
```

Is equivalent to

```cs
Task.Run(() =>
{
    _service.ProcessFailedOrders();
}).Wait();
```

Note the `Task` returned by `ProcessFailedOrders` is not returned and is not awaited. Hence you are using the `Task.Run(Action action)` overload, which completes immediately after the `ProcessFailedOrders`is called. You need to use the `Task.Run(Func<Task> task)` overload.

You can fix it like this

```cs
Task.Run(async () => { await _service.ProcessFailedOrders(); }).Wait();
```

Which is equivalent to

```cs
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    // the Task is awaited now
    await _service.ProcessFailedOrders();
}).Wait();
```

Or like this

```cs
Task.Run(() => _service.ProcessFailedOrders()).Wait();
```

Which is equivalent to

```cs
Task.Run(() =>
{
    // the Task is returned now
    return _service.ProcessFailedOrders();
}).Wait();
```

Or like this

```cs
Task.Run(_service.ProcessFailedOrders).Wait();
```