# Windows phone httpclient not working

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have the following code. The async call never returns anything. Even for google.com.

```
try
            {
                using (
                    var client = new HttpClient()) { 
                var response = client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");
                Debug.WriteLine("Coming here1"+response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
                if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // by calling .Result you are performing a synchronous call
                    Debug.WriteLine("Coming here1");
                    var responseContent = response.Result.Content;

                    // by calling .Result you are synchronously reading the result
                    string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    //Console.WriteLine(responseString);
                }
                else { Debug.WriteLine("else"); }
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
               Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using WebClient?

Comment: NO specfic reason. I heard httpclient is the new one with improvements...I read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435520/why-use-httpclient-for-synchronous-connection and followed

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
try{
     WebClient wc = new WebClient();
     wc.DownloadStringCompleted+= (sender,args) => {
        Debug.WriteLine(args.results);
     };
     wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(@"http://www.Google.com",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

}
catch(Exception e){ Debug.WriteLine(e.Message); }
```

Comment: Sure. Please let me know if you come across any how to use tutorials for Httpclient on phone

Comment: But I figured the HttpClient option..here is the working code `code`String strResult = await signUpReq.GetStringAsync(finalUri);`code`

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be awaiting your Async call.

Try changing `var response = client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");` to `var response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");`

Remember to mark your method as `async`.

you're also blocking on your async call `ReadAsStringAsync().Result`. As with client.GetAsync, make sure to await the call instead of blocking with `Result`. This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) speaks a bit on the topic.

Read up a bit on async/await. You'll love it once you get the hang of it.