# asp.net HttpClient throws exception on 400 errors when sending synchronous requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpclient

The following code for me is throwing an exception when I get a 400 error.  Thus I'm never able to get return response as the exception is always caught.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    try
    {
        var data = "...";

        var RequestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        var requestUri = new Uri("url to error");
        var content = new StringContent(RequestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)  // it never gets in here since an exception is thrown
        {
            throw new HttpException(500, "PhantomJS status request failed");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("PhantomJS status request failed", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `client.PostAsynch(...)` but the title if your question refers to synchronous requests? Which is it?

Comment: synchronous...  I'm using code similar to what is recommended in this post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435520/why-use-httpclient-for-synchronous-connection   Adding .Result to the end of PostAsync causes the request to be synchronous.

Comment: What is the class name of the exception?

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: is the exception of type HttpRequestException  ?

Comment: Turns out it was a problem not with httpclient but with the server I'm making a request to.  It was not handling the keep-alive headers correctly.