# MVC call api controller PostAsJsonAsync from Session_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asynchronous, global-asax

I am doing an `MVC 5 APP` and i am calling a Api Controller using `PostAsJsonAsync` like this

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl + "Method/Action",param);
```

I got this error

> [InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.]

I am doing this call from `Global.asax` `Session_Start`.

The intention is to register every person Access the site. 
I have to modify `Session_Start` to `async void Session_Start`

How can manage this situation? Making the call process Non-Asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

I look 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435520/why-use-httpclient-for-synchronous-connection)

and replace

```html
public static async Task<long> Insert_SessionStart(
{
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl + "Method/Action", param);

 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<long>().Result;
  
  }
```

for this

```html
public static long Insert_SessionStart()
{
 var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl + "Method/acti", param).Result;
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<long>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
 
}
```

This way I avoid putting `await` Method in `Session`_start.