# C# - Having trouble iterating over a dynamic JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I am trying to pull JSON data from a website and I am having some trouble iterating over the objects it returns. Can someone please assist with navigating this structure? I am confused by it not being uniform.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "myToken");
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://app.website.com/data/");

    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("getData.json?item=myItem").Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);

    dynamic jsonArray = result.results;
                
    foreach (var item in jsonArray.items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.date1);
    }
}
```

The JSON array I'm dealing with is below. My goal is to iterate through `item` and get all of the `date1` and `date2` values. I don't need anything else.

```
{
    "results": {
        "copyright": "Copyright",
        "items": [{
            "info": {
                "longname": "XXX",
                "shortname": "YYY"
            },
            "item": [{
                "date1": "2022-01-01",
                "date2": "2022-01-05",
            }, {
                "date1": "2022-04-01",
                "date2": "2021-04-07",
            }],
            "key": {
                "keyName": "AAA",
                "keySym": "BBB",
            },
            "symString": "BBB"
        }],
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: what is dynamic or not being uniform about the json you provided?

Comment: Is there a reason you're deserializing to `dynamic` rather than building a concrete model or using `JToken.Parse`?

Comment: I had never used anything other than `dynamic` before so that was the only reason. I considered this json somewhat irregular because it had additional items like `key` though I know that doesn't necessarily make it irregular. It was just more complex than what I was used to working with.

Comment: maybe consider using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022 - and than deserialize to the generated classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making extra work for yourself by using `dynamic` as you lose IntelliSense as well as compile-time type checking.  The underlying type returned by Json.NET for `dynamic` will typically be some subtype of [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jtoken.htm), so the easiest way to accomplish your task is to deserialize to `JToken` and use [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) like so:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(jsonString);
var dates = result.SelectTokens("results.items[*].item[*]")
    .Select(i => new { date1 = i["date1"].ToObject<DateOnly>(), date2 = i["date2"].ToObject<DateOnly>() });
foreach (var item in dates)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Date1={item.date1}, Date2={item.date2}.");
}
```

Which prints

```
Date1=01/01/2022, Date2=01/05/2022.
Date1=04/01/2022, Date2=04/07/2021.
```

Notes:

- The query string `"results.items[*].item[*]"` passed to `SelectTokens()` is a [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) query that includes wildcards to select all items in the `"items"` array and the nested `"item"` array.
- [`DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0) was introduced in .NET 6.  In earlier versions use `DateTime`.
- Using `httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result` can sometimes cause deadlocks, see *[An async/await example that causes a deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15021304)* for details.  If this happens, consider converting your code to be asynchronous, or see *[What's the "right way" to use HttpClient synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53529061)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RmMhpA)

Comment: Is there any difference between `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(jsonString)` and `JToken.Parse(jsonString)`?

Comment: @gunr2171 - Very little.  `JToken.Parse(jsonString)` automatically loads line information while `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(jsonString)` does not, leading to slightly greater memory usage.  It's also easier to pass settings when using `DeserializeObject()`.  But really I just used `DeserializeObject()` because OP was already using it.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you!

Comment: How would you access the `keyName` property under `key`? I tried `results.items[*].key` but that didn't work

Comment: @eek -  `"results.items[*].key.keyName"`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/RmMhpA.

Comment: @dbc - sometimes there is an optional keyName. if I try to select it when it's not there, it breaks. (example would be trying to select `date3` in your example. how can I check this safely? i have tried finding methods to list keys but i am not sure if it's supported with my method

Comment: @eek - I would need to see a [mcve] showing both possible JSON versions.  Since it has been a couple months since you asked this question, I would suggest asking a new question showing where you are stuck.

Comment: I posted a new question here if you wouldn't mind taking a peek: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77856068/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-a-field-exists-before-trying-to-query-it-in-a-json