# Why my List is null after being assigned in a function call?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronization

This might be a silly question. But when I modified one example from Live SDK example, got a weird problem.

I was thinking the root cause is async function GetAll() was used synchronously.

Below is the code snippet, I put the problem as comments. Thanks in advance!

```
class SkyeDriveViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<SkyDriveItem> folderList = null;
    public List<SkyDriveItem> FolderList
    {
        get { return folderList; }
        private set
        {
            if (value != folderList)
            {

                folderList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("FolderList");
            }
        }
    }

    private async void GetAll(string desiredPath)
    {
        FolderList = new List<SkyDriveItem>();

        this.liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(SkyDrivePage.Session);
        try
        {
            LiveOperationResult operationResult = await this.liveClient.GetAsync(desiredPath);
            dynamic result = operationResult.Result;

            dynamic items = result.data;
            foreach (dynamic item in items)
            {
                SkyDriveItem newItem = new SkyDriveItem(item);
                if (newItem.IsFolder)
                {
                    FolderList.Add(newItem);
                }

            }

        }
        catch (LiveConnectException e)
        {
        }
        //**till here, FolderList was assigned**
    }

    public void InitList()
    {
        Debugger.Log();
        GetAll(SKYDRIVEINITPATH);
        Debugger.LogWhen(eDebugger.LogTiming.Exit); 
        //**till here, FolderList had zero item**
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general having an `async void` function is a warning sign.  You should only have such a method for an event handler.  The appropriate return type for `GetAll` is `Task`, or possibly even `Task<List<SkyDriveItem>>`.

The issue is that calling `GetAll` will only execute code until it hits the first `await` call, at which point it returns to the caller and the remainder of the method will be executed asynchronously.

The problem here is that because the method is `void` you have no way of knowing when it's done.  You have a "fire and forget" method and can never know when your list is actually ready.  If `GetAll` returns a task then you can `await` that task and be sure that your list has actually been populated.

Comment: +1. `GatAll` should return `Task` and than you can call `Wait` on result if calling function *must* by synchronous.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If the caller needs it to be synchronous then the method probably shouldn't be asynchronous at all to begin with...

Comment: I found a solution from here[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously). So the **public static void RunSync(Func<Task> task)** seems to be the solution.

Comment: @tao Even that won't help you if you don't convert the function into one that returns a `Task` instead of `void`.

Comment: @Servy You are absolutely right about `asyn void` and `await`. I tried to use event handler, it started working. Thanks again!