# What is the difference between .Wait() vs .GetAwaiter().GetResult()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

My method returns `Task`. I want to wait until it finished. What should I use
`.Wait()` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Both are a synchronous wait for the result of the operation (and you should avoid those if possible).

The difference is mainly in handling exceptions. With `Wait`, the exception stack trace is unaltered and represents the actual stack at the time of the exception, so if you have a piece of code that runs on a thread-pool thread, you'd have a stack like

```
ThreadPoolThread.RunTask
YourCode.SomeWork
```

On the other hand, `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will rework the stack trace to take all the asynchronous context into account, ignoring that some parts of the code execute on the UI thread, and some on a ThreadPool thread, and some are simply asynchronous I/O. So your stack trace will reflect a synchronous-like step through *your code*:

```
TheSyncMethodThatWaitsForTheAsyncMethod
YourCode.SomeAsyncMethod
SomeAsync
YourCode.SomeWork
```

This tends to make exception stack traces a lot more useful, to say the least. You can see where `YourCode.SomeWork` was called *in the context of your application*, rather than "the physical way it was run".

An example of how this works is in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs,ca9850c71672bd54) (non-contractual, of course).

Comment: [Task.GetAwaiter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  returns a [TaskAwaiter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However, the doc for [TaskAwaiter.GetResult()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.getresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) advises: *"This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."* Can you comment?

Comment: @DavidRR The whole `TaskAwaiter` is an implementation detail. On the other hand, the awaitable/awaiter mechanism is documented, and uses duck-typing - `GetAwaiter` is to `await` as `GetEnumerator` is to `foreach` or `Dispose` is to `using`. All this is defined in the C# specification regardless of the particular awaiter being used - note that `Task.GetAwaiter` is "intended for compiler use rather than for use in application code." But the point is that the intended use is to do an `await`, not `Wait()` nor `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` - but `GetResult` gives you nicer stacks if you need it.

Comment: @Luaan `using` and `Dispose()` does not use ducktyping. This only works when implementing `IDisposable`. Ducktyping is used for `foreach` and `GetEnumerator()` as for `await` and `GetAwaiter()` though.

Comment: @codingdave Oh, you're right, there is a type-check while compiling the C# code. The native code doesn't actually do a virtual call, but that's not quite the same as a duck typing.

Answer (score 0):

Try your best to avoid synchronously blocking on an asynchronous task.

In those rare exceptional cases,
`GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will preserve the task exceptions,

If you use `Wait` it will throw AggregateException.

Refer to [@stephen-cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)'s blog post ['a-tour-of-task-part-6-results'](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html)