# Why does Exception from async void crash the app but from async Task is swallowed

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I understand that an `async Task`'s Exceptions can be caught by:

```
try { await task; }
catch { }
```

while an `async void`'s cannot because it cannot be awaited.

But why is it that when the async **Task** is not awaited (just like the async **void** one) the `Exception` is swallowed, while the **void**'s one crashes the application?

**Caller**: `ex();`

**Called**:

```
async void ex() { throw new Exception(); }
async Task ex() { throw new Exception(); }
```

Comment: Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### TL;DR

This is because `async void` shouldn't be used! `async void` is only there to make legacy code work (e.g. event handlers in WindowsForms and WPF).

### Technical details

This is because of how the C# compiler generates code for the `async` methods.

You should know that behind `async`/`await` there's a state machine (`IAsyncStateMachine` implementation) generated by the compiler.

When you declare an `async` method, a state machine `struct` will be generated for it. For your `ex()` method, this state machine code will look like:

```
void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        this.state = -2;
        this.builder.SetException(exception);
    }
}
```

Note that `this.builder.SetException(exception);` statement. For a `Task`-returning `async` method, this will be an `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder` object. For a `void ex()` method, it will be an `AsyncVoidMethodBuilder`.

The `ex()` method body will be replaced by the compiler with something like this:

```
private static Task ex()
{
    ExAsyncStateMachine exasm;
    exasm.builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
    exasm.state = -1;
    exasm.builder.Start<ExAsyncStateMachine>(ref exasm);
    return exasm.builder.Task;
}
```

(and for the `async void ex()`, there will be no last `return` line)

The method builder's `Start<T>` method will call the `MoveNext` method of the state machine. The state machine's method catches the exception in its `catch` block. This exception should normally be observed on the `Task` object - the `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.SetException` method stores that exception object in the `Task` instance. When we drop that `Task` instance (no `await`), we don't see the exception at all, but the exception itself isn't thrown anymore.

In the state machine for `async void ex()`, there's an `AsyncVoidMethodBuilder` instead. Its `SetException` method looks different: since there's no `Task` where to store the exception, it has to be thrown. It happens in a different way, however, not just a normal `throw`:

```
AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ThrowAsync(exception, synchronizationContext);
```

The logic inside that `AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ThrowAsync` helper decides:

- If there's a `SynchronizationContext` (e.g. we're on a UI thread of a WPF app), the exception will be **posted** on that context.
- Otherwise, the exception will be queued on a `ThreadPool` thread.

In both cases, the exception won't be caught by a `try-catch` block that might be set up around the `ex()` call (unless you have a special `SynchronizationContext` that can do this, see e.g. Stephen Cleary's [`AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context/AsyncContext.cs)).

The reason is simple: when we **post** a `throw` action or **enqueue** it, we then simply return from the `ex()` method and thus leave the `try-catch` block. Then, the posted/enqueued action is executed (either on the same or on a different thread).

Answer (score 10):

**Please read important note at bottom.**

The `async void` method will crash the application because there is no `Task` object for the C# compiler to push the exception into. On a functional level, the `async` keyword on a `Task`-returning method is just heavy syntax sugar that tells the compiler to rewrite your method in terms of a `Task` object using the various methods available on the object as well as utilities such as `Task.FromResult`, `Task.FromException`, and `Task.FromCancelled`, or sometimes `Task.Run`, or equivalents from the compiler's point of view. This means that code like:

```
async Task Except()
{
    throw new Exception { };
}
```

gets turned into *approximately*:

```
Task Except()
{
    return Task.FromException(new Exception { });
}
```

and so when you call `Task`-returning `async` methods that `throw`, the program doesn't crash because no exception is actually being thrown; instead, a `Task` object is created in an "excepted" state and is returned to the caller. As mentioned previously, an `async void`-decorated method doesn't have a `Task` object to return, and so the compiler does not attempt to rewrite the method in terms of a `Task` object, but instead only tries to deal with getting the values of awaited calls.

#### More Context

`Task`-returning methods can actually cause exceptions too, even when not being awaited because the `async` keyword is what causes the swallowing, so if it is not present, the exceptions in the method will not be swallowed, such as the following.

```
Task Except() // Take note that there is no async modifier present.
{
    throw new Exception { }; // This will now throw no matter what.
    return Task.FromResult(0); // Task<T> derives from Task so this is an implicit cast.
}
```

The reason why awaiting a call will actually `throw` the exception supposedly thown in a `Task`-returning `async` method is because the `await` keyword is supposed to throw the swallowed `Exception`s by design to make debugging easier in an asynchronous context.

#### Important Note

The way that these "rewrites" are actually processed by the compiler and manifested by the compiled code may be different than how I have implied, but are roughly equivalent on a functional level.

Comment: Exceptional answer Alex.

Answer (score 1):

Because, your methods are not executed asynchronously.

Execution will run synchronously until it "meet" `await` keyword.

So in case of `void` application will throw an exception, because exception occurs in the current execution context.

In case of `Task` even exception thrown synchronously it will be wrapped in the `Task` and returned to the caller.

You should get desired behaviour with `void` as well if you will use `await` in the function.

```
async void Ex()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: `in case of void application will throw an exception, because exception occurs in the current execution context` - So why is it not caught when wrapped in a try-catch block (in the caller)?

Comment: `await Task.Delay(1000);` - Nope. Still crashes the app.

Comment: _while the void's one crashes the application_ - void should