# Are async console applications supported in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

At some point in time the CoreCLR supported async main entry points. See http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/async-console-apps-on-net-coreclr.html

However both the following programs are not working in .NET Core RTM

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

These both fail with the error:

> error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Are async console applications supported in .NET Core RTM?

Comment: Note that [`async Main` support is currently planned for C# 7.0](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md).

Comment: @svick actually async Main support has been added in c# 7.1,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main - In your visual studio 2017 project, go to project properties -> build -> advanced, then change your language version to 7.1 (or higher)

Comment: Remember to change ```properties -> build -> advanced -> language version``` for Debug AND Release build types, else project will fail on Publish.

Comment: In my project, 'async Main' only works if i used Task instead of void. With void i received the error 'CS5001'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't specify the 'async' modifier on the 'Main' method of a console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Yes, the `async Main` functions are supported since `.NET Core 2.0`.

```
dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.0
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  cdcd1928c9

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  16.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.16.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d
```

The support for the `async Main` functions is introduced in C# version 7.1. However, this functionality is not available out of the box. To make use of this feature you need explicitly specify the C# version 7.1  in your `.csproj` file, either by including

```
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
```

or by

```
<LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
```

For example for the ASP.NET core 2.0 project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

where the Main function can be rewritten as following:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

...
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   await BuildWebHost(args).RunAsync();
}
...
```

References:

1. [C# 7 Series, Part 2: Async Main](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/)
2. [Champion "Async Main" (C# 7.1)](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/97)

Comment: You can also set the language version (now?) in the project properties; Build -> Advanced -> Language version.

Comment: By default this option has value "latest major version" and equals to 7.0, not 7.1! Change it manually.

Comment: First reference link is dead; here's the wayback machine cache: https://web.archive.org/web/20190118084407/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/

Comment: The link is dead because Microsoft employees need to migrate their blogs manually apparently: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aeaa91cd-56ed-441f-8d22-ec0febfa8850/where-has-this-blog-gone?forum=tnwiki

Answer (score 58):

**Update**: Async main is supported natively by C# 7.1! See Evgeny's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958948/3191599) above.

I'll keep the below workaround for posterity, but it is no longer needed. `async main` is way simpler, use that if you can!

---

This is my preferred workaround **in C# less than 7.1**:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

`GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is the same as `.Wait` (blocking synchronously), but [is preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31742125/3191599) because it unwraps exceptions.

Answer (score 11):

Support for async entry points was removed a while back.

See [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/113) on the aspnet/announcements github.

> We decided to move towards unification of entry point semantics with
> desktop CLR.
>
> Obsolete in RC1:
>
> Support for async/Task<> Main.
>
> Support for instantiating of entry point type (Program).
>
> The Main method should be public static void Main or public static int Main.
>
> Support for injecting dependencies into the Program class's constructor and Main method.
>
> Use PlatformServices and CompilationServices instead.
>
> To get to IApplicationEnvironment, IRuntimeEnvironment, IAssemblyLoaderContainer, IAssemblyLoadContextAccessor,
> ILibraryManager
> use Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default
> static object.
>
> To get to ILibraryExporter, ICompilerOptionsProvider use the Microsoft.Extensions.CompilationAbstractions.CompilationServices.Default
> static object.
>
> Support for CallContextServiceLocator. Use PlatformServices and CompilationServices instead.
>
> Same as above.
>
> These would be removed in RC2: #106