# Awaiting SQL client async in the Main Method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core

I have this code:

`Program.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace sql
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = new List<SampleItem>();
            result = Inventory.QueryStock();

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.ItemCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`sql.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace sql
{
    public class Inventory
    {
        public static async Task<List<SampleItem>> QueryStock()
        {
            if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQL_CONNECTION_STRING") == null)
               Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SQL_CONNECTION_STRING","Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;user id=sa;password=sql@123");

            else 
                Console.WriteLine("sql connection already registered: ");

            var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQL_CONNECTION_STRING");
            var sql = @"
                        SELECT
                            T0.ItemCode, T0.WhsCode, T0.OnHand, 
                            T1.AvgPrice, T0.OnHand * T1.AvgPrice as [Value]
                        FROM 
                            OITW T0
                        INNER JOIN
                            OITM T1 on T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode
                        WHERE
                            T0.itemcode LIKE 'RM%' AND T0.WhsCode ='RM' AND T0.onHand > 0";
            var items = new List<SampleItem>();

            using (var cnx = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnx))
                {
                    await cnx.OpenAsync();

                    using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            var item = new SampleItem
                                 {
                                     ItemCode = reader.GetString(0)
                                 };
                            items.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
               }
            }

            return items;
        } 
    }

    public class SampleItem
    {
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and added the required dependencies `System.Data.SqlClient` to the JSON file to get:

`project.json`

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
        "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I've is the returned async result from the `QueryStock()` is not captured in the `Main` function, due to the unexisting of `await` and if I used `await` then it ask for the `Main` to be `async`, and if I made it `async` it tells the `Entry point Main` can not be `async`?

**UPDATE**

Considering the question had been blocked for answers, I just re-writing [Rubbke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128852/rubbleford) comment that solved by issue, for easy eye catching:

```
result = Inventory.QueryStock().Result;
```

another solution I found that help as well is:

```
result = Inventory.QueryStock().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: I found the solution, I should be using `x = Inventory.QueryStock().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: Inventory.QueryStock().Result

Comment: @RubbleFord thanks, you solved it perfectly.

Comment: @RubbleFord: You should avoid using `.Result` as it wraps the exceptions in `AggregateException` whereas `GetResult()` throws the original exception. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31742125/455493

Comment: @Tseng the documentation for GetResult() 

This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. Ends the wait for the completion of the asynchronous task.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.aspx