# c# ReadAsJsonAsync in framework 4.5

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I am used to work in Net Core. When I call a RestApi I read retrieved data like this.

```html
  HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, param).Result;
    value = response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<R>().Result;
```

Now, I am back in Framework 4.5 and i need a replace to

> ReadAsJsonAsync

What is the best way to replace it?

Thanks

Comment: Why do use the Async methods but did not want them behave async? That is like playing with water but did not like to become wet ...

Comment: Use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/

Comment: Do not use Task.Result, instead do [GetAwaiter().GetResult();](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530225/6640527)

Comment: @Unnamed or indeed, better yet, `await` it if possible.

Comment: @Jon Yes, the only case to not await async code will be when for some reason you need to run it synchronously, just in that case we will prefer GetAwaiter.GetResult() over Task.Result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just install the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) NuGet package and implement the `ReadAsJsonAsync` extension method yourself. It's pretty simple:

```
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T> ReadAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpContent content)
    {
        var dataAsString = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(dataAsString);
    }
}
```

By the way, you should await async methods and not block on the `Result` property:

```
value = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<R>();
```

Comment: if possible use [ConfigureAwait(false)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13494570/6640527)

Comment: That is already included in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/ => ReadAsAsync<T> which is available for .net Framework 4.5 and up

Comment: @SirRufo Which namespace?  I am here specifically because I cannot find this method in Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client, using Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: @Daniel https://fuget.org is a great source for looking into nuget packages. Here we go: https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/5.2.7/netstandard2.0/lib/System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll/System.Net.Http/HttpContentExtensions#ReadAsAsync

Comment: @SirRufo Ah, I should have deleted this comment.  I had forgotten I actually pulled the trigger on it.  I found the method, and the fault was all mine.  I was looking specifically for ReadAsJsonAsync--as named in this question and answer--but did not notice the correct name (ReadAsAsync) in your comment.  Once I did, it was easy to find in System.Net.Http.Formatting.  Thank you, though.