# Error when attaching file to System.Net.Mail. How do I fix this error?

Tags: c#

Trying to send an email with an attachment.  However I am getting an error:

> "Cannot convert from
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to
>   'System.Net.Mail.Attachment'

My error occurs in the line             `Attachments.Add(GetAttachment(attachmentFileName));`

I have tried various conversions (see code) but I dont quite see what the issue is.  I know the solution is right in front of me but I dont see it.

```
public class NonFERosterEmail : BaseNotificationEmail<OfferViewModel>
{
    public NonFERosterEmail(OfferViewModel vm, string emailList, string attachmentFileName) : base(vm)
    {
        To.AddRange(GetTo(emailList));
        Body = GetBody();
        Subject = GetSubject();
        //Attachments.Add(new Attachment(GetAttachment(attachmentFileName)));
        Attachments.Add(GetAttachment(attachmentFileName));
        From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectEmailTo"]);
    }

    //public async Task<List<Attachment>> GetAttachment(string attachmentFileName)
    public async Task<Attachment> GetAttachment(string attachmentFileName)
    {
        //var ret = new List<Attachment>();

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azureStorageAccount"]); 
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("attachments");
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(attachmentFileName);

        var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(attachmentFileName);
        Stream target = new MemoryStream();
        await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(target);
        target.Position = 0;
        //ret.Add(new Attachment(target, attachmentFileName, contentType));

        Attachment ret = new Attachment(target, attachmentFileName, contentType);

        return ret;
    }

//remainder of code left out for brevity
}
```

I expect the `GetAttachment` to return a correct Attachment object which would be added to the Mail object and sent successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answers from @SLaks and @Roman Marusyk are correct, but it looks like you are calling `GetAttachment` from the constructor, which is not asynchronous. As such you would not be able to use `await` without using an `async` method. Try using the result property of `GetAttachment` as shown below.

```
Attachments.Add(GetAttachment(attachmentFileName).Result);
```

A better solution would be to use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, which as @Roman Marusyk pointed out and shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult), if the method fails it will throw the exception directly rather than throwing an `AggregateException`.

A better solution would be to use the following

```
Attachments.Add(GetAttachment(attachmentFileName).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

Comment: `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is preferred over `Task.Result` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult

Comment: @RomanMarusyk thanks the suggestion, I have updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

To get the value from a `Task<T>`, you must make your method `async` and `await` the task.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` when call method that returns `Task`, so instead of this

```
Attachments.Add(GetAttachment(attachmentFileName));
```

Use:

```
Attachments.Add(await GetAttachment(attachmentFileName));
```

or

```
Attachments.Add(GetAttachment(attachmentFileName).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```