# HttpResponseMessage to string

Tags: c#

I am calling a method of which returns Task, in the calling method I need to read the response in form of string.

Here's the code that I have put:

```
static public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Validate(string baseUri,HttpContent content) {
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();   
    response = await client.PostAsync(baseUri,content);    
    return response;
}

public string test(){
    string postJson = "{Login = \"user\", Password =  \"pwd\"}";
    HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(postJson, 
    UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage result=Validate(Uri,stringContent);
    var json = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

I expect string but this error is thrown:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>' to 
'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'
```

Comment: Try HttpResponseMessage result=Validate(Uri,stringContent).Result;

Comment: @auburg: blocking this way could possibly [cause a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: in that case the OP needs to await the call to Validate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is at:

```
HttpResponseMessage result=Validate(Uri,stringContent);
```

`Validate` is returning a task, not a `HttpResponseMessage`.

Change that to:

```
var result = Validate(Uri,stringContent).Result;
```

Just to clean up the code a bit and avoid using `Result` if you can afford to change it like:

```
static public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Validate(string baseUri, HttpContent content)
{  
   return await client.PostAsync(baseUri,content);
}

public async Task<string> test()
{
   var postJson = "{Login = \"user\", Password =  \"pwd\"}";
   var stringContent = new StringContent(postJson, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   var result = await Validate(Uri,stringContent);
   return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Be consistent with your coding style. As to why calling `.Result` is bad, as people are pointing out in the comments, check [this blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Calling `.Result` is bad, because of possible locks.

Comment: Yes, but that's a whole different issue. It's not my responsibility to redesign his code :)

Comment: @swdon: but you could reflect that in the answer. Remember that SO is a source of knowledge not only directly to the OP but also to other people visiting this years later. An answer that suggests a possible bad approach could definitely be improved then.

Comment: return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); - can I convert this to plain string?

Comment: What do you mean convert to plain string?

Comment: I meant, I need a String instead of Task<String>.

Comment: `return result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`

Answer (score 0):

1. Just for readability change the method name from `Validate(..)` to `ValidateAsync(..)`. Just to make clear that this method returns a task and you have to await it.
2. You're missing an await when calling your Validate method. If you do not want or can make the caller async then use the method `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` and you'll get what you want.
3. Replace `ReadAsStringAsync().Result` with `ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Like others wrote in comments calling `.Result` is bad because it could cause locks. The same applies in general to `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` but calling them is preferred over calling `Result`. The best option is to use `await/async`.

When you want to know whats the difference between `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`  vs calling `Result` you can read this:
[Is Task.Result the same as .GetAwaiter.GetResult()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult)

Answer (score 0):

Method `Validate` returns the task and is asynchronous. Basically you can call this method in two different ways:

1) await the result of `Validate` in another async method, like this...

```
public async Task<string> test() {
    string postJson = "{Login = \"user\", Password =  \"pwd\"}";
    HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(postJson, 
        UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage result = await Validate(Uri,stringContent);
    var json = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

2) block current execution while waiting for this resul, like this...

```
public string test() {
    string postJson = "{Login = \"user\", Password =  \"pwd\"}";
    HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(postJson, 
        UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage result = Validate(Uri,stringContent).Result;
    var json = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Choose the 1st way by default unless you really have an urge to block the calling thread.

Note that when using 2nd solution in WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET apps you will probably have a deadlock. modifying `Validate` method like this should solve the problem:

```
response = await client.PostAsync(baseUri,content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write:

```
var json = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over the existing answers? The existing answers also use `Content.ReadAsStringAsync().`; the only difference is that you use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of e.g. `Result`. What's the value of that here?