# How can I do this Synchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, async-await, ringcentral

I've been looking at sample code from RingCentral API. I'd like to execute the following code synchronously.

I've begun familiarizing myself with 'ContinueWith'.

```
//From API sample
using (var rc = new RestClient("clientID", "clientSecret", "serverURL"))
    {
        await rc.Authorize("username", "extension", "password");
        var result = await rc.Restapi(apiVersion).Account(accountId).Recording(recordingId).Get();
    }
//My first attempt (I am unable to get the value of the result)
using (var rc = new RestClient("clientID", "clientSecret", "serverURL"))
    {
        rc.Authorize("username", "extension", "password").ContinueWith(rc.Restapi(apiVersion).Account(accountId).Recording(recordingId).Get());
    }
```

Comment: My first question will be **Why?**

Comment: The _why_ part is necessary to know if @bluesky's answer is safe to use. State your application type.

Comment: You may want to check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530225/6560579)

Answer (score 1):

To make it synchronous, remove all `await`, and use `.Wait()` and `.Result` like this:

```
rc.Authorize("username", "extension", "password").Wait();
var result = rc.Restapi(apiVersion).Account(accountId).Recording(recordingId).Get().Result;
```

However you really ***should*** be using async/await to call an API.  For example, with [C# 7.1 even Main() can be declared async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main), meaning that all subsequent method calls can use async/await throughout your codebase.

Comment: `async Main` is just [syntactic sugar](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/) that is compiled to a synchronous blocking `Main`.