# why does the first button click freeze and then not

Tags: c#

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = Get2().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    richTextBox1.AppendText(a);
}

public async Task<string>Get2()
{
    return await "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SMAPPNYU/ProgrammerGroup/master/LargeDataSets/sample-tweet.raw.json".GetStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The first button click hangs for a moment then it works fine. why does the form freeze at the first time click the button?

Comment: Well the first time it's making an HTTP request.  Maybe its caching the response?  Use your debugger or Fiddler.

Comment: Try making `Button1_Click` async aswell

Comment: there is no await so async is not needed

Comment: This needs `async` _and_ `await`. In the BtnClick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have defined `GetStringAsync()` as an extension method, which you havent shown here (or maybe it's part of a library you're using). But assuming it uses `HttpClient` in the background, then the first try works as you would expect, but leaves the TCP connection open. The second request uses the same connection, which saves the time it takes to set up the connection and do the SSL handshake.

That's just a wild guess though. I'd have to see the code for `GetStringAsync()` to give a better guess.

Side note: consider making `Button1_Click` async and using `await`. What you have right now will freeze the UI until the request returns. If you use `await`, it won't.

Comment: the `GetStringAsync` is from the FlurHttp library https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-http/

Answer (score 2):

That the reason that the freezes is because you use a async call synchronusly (see [Is Task.Result the same as .GetAwaiter.GetResult()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult)) in the UI thread. Try using `async/await` there aswell (`GetResult()` will block the UI thread like `.Result` does):

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = await Get2().ConfigureAwait(true); // true needed to continue on the UI thread
    richTextBox1.AppendText(a);
}

public async Task<string> Get2()
{
    return await "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SMAPPNYU/ProgrammerGroup/master/LargeDataSets/sample-tweet.raw.json".GetStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: The button click handler should return `void` not `Task`. Event handlers are the exception to the rule that `async` methods should return either `Task` or `Task<T>`

Comment: could you test it out it freeze also the first click

Comment: How do you define "freeze" ? Is the UI freezing so where you can't even move the window? Or is the value in the text box just not updating? How long is it freezing for?

Comment: If the payload would be much bigger the ui could also freeze during the update `richTextBox1.AppendText(a);` but I don't think that would be noticeable with such a small payload

Comment: @schokoBong on my side there is no freezing of the UI whatsoever, I assume you mean why is the value not updating instantly after the click. --> Gabriel Luci's answer

Comment: no, if I click the button I cant do anything for 1-2 secounds then If I example spam the button It dont freeze