# Does GetAwaiter() throw a single exception?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I am trying to understand why the following `Task.Run` and `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` would be used instead of `await ... <result>`

```
(var success, var response) = Task.Run(() => HTTPHelper.SendRequest<SomeJsonResponse>( ... )).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Does the code above throw, as [this article shows](https://codurance.com/2018/12/06/wait-and-getawaiter/), an `Exception` and not an `AggregateException`? If so, I believe that is why this structure was chosen.

Is it possible to use `async ... await` in this situation and have the same result? (I assume not, if the single exception requirement is only possible with the code above.)

Comment: *"instead of `await ... .Result`"* - You never use `.Result` with `await`. It just wouldn't work. The `await` keyword unwraps the result for you.

Comment: Microsoft's articles on asynchronous programming are actually quite well written. You might benefit from reading through them. Start here: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can and **should** use `async await` :

```
(var success, var response) = await HTTPHelper.SendRequest<SomeJsonResponse>( ... )
```

Then there is no need to wrap it into the Task. I assume `.SendRequest<SomeJsonResponse>()` returns the `Task`.

FYI: `.Wait()`, `.Result` or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` are all thread blocking executions

Comment: I found this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530225/71376

Comment: Actually, in answer to your question, I believe the `.SendRequest` does not return a task, partly because it is a legacy method, hence `Task.Run()`

Comment: @MattW yes it’s basically workaround if you aren’t able to change method signature to return Task

Comment: Thanks :) Looks like there's lots of differing opinions (or at least, history) on this topic. Even the post marked as the original of this duplicate appears to be claiming the answer in two different directions (well, the responses do, anyway.)

Comment: @MattW Everyone agrees that you should use `await` if you can. The disagreements are only about how to go about synchronously waiting on an asynchronous method (which you should make an effort to avoid doing in the first place).