# queueClient.SendAsync(message) doesnt send msg consistently

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

The below program sends the message to the queue, however most of the times the message is not sent.

I am using the *Sender()* method (as shown below) in my class library. This is being called from a Cloud Service(Worker Role). Please help to identify why the message is not consistently sent and correcting the code.

```cs
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sender();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Sender()
    {
        var ConnectionString = "<<Connectionstring>>";
        var QueueName = "samplequeue";

        var queueClient = new QueueClient(ConnectionString, QueueName);

        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                // Create a new message to send to the queue
                string messageBody = $"Message {i}";
                var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));


                // Write the body of the message to the console
                Console.WriteLine($"Sending message: {messageBody}");

                // Send the message to the queue
                queueClient.SendAsync(message);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message queue failed\n" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message queued");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you try to fix the code first and await the sending command? It was pointed out in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/331#issuecomment-579935655) you've raised earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you're not `awaiting` the execution of an `async method`.

```
queueClient.SendAsync(message)
```

One option would be to change the above call and wait for the execution to complete

```
await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
```

In this case you will need to make `Sender` method `async` as well and then wait for it to complete in your `Main` method.

Other option would be to use `Sync` version of the method:

```
queueClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for the response. if i add await/async, the whole caller methods have to be async, which i don't have control, as the Sender method will be called by other applications also. and i don't see Send method in the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.QueueClient class. can you point me to the right class?

Comment: `if i add await/async, the whole caller methods have to be async, which i don't have control, as the Sender method will be called by other applications also` - That's correct.

Comment: `and i don't see Send method in the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.QueueClient class. can you point me to the right class?` - I looked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.send?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueClient_Send_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage_ which I believe this is an older SDK. Can you tell me which SDK you're using?`

Answer (score 0):

You must wait on the call to complete. Otherwise it will be run in the background.

That means that Message 4 might complete after Message 3 (since you have a loop) or that it wont complete at all if your console application exits before it have a chance.

Since you are using a synchronous application, you can invkoe `Send()` like this:

```
queueClient.SendAsync(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

See [.Result vs .GetAwaiter().GetResult()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult)