# C# Telegram.Bot SendTextMessageAsync dosen't send any messages

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I'm trying to implement simple sending messages via telegram bot. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{

  class Program
  {
    public static string ApiKey { get; set; } = "MyApiKey";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TelegramBotClient client = new TelegramBotClient(ApiKey);
        client.SendTextMessageAsync(MyChatId, "Hello World");          
    }
  }
}
```

But this code dosen't send any message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SendTextMessageAsync` method returns a `Task`. Try awaiting it.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    TelegramBotClient client = new TelegramBotClient(ApiKey);
    await client.SendTextMessageAsync(MyChatId, "Hello World");
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you. How do you think, is it possible to use "SendTextMessage" without "await"?

Comment: It seems there is no synchronous alternative in the TelegramBotClient.
If you have to, you can synchronize it. For example like this client.SendTextMessageAsync(MyChatId, "Hello World").GetAwaiter.GetResult()
But I would avoid it if possible because there are caveats with deadlocks and exceptions handling.

More details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult