# HttpClient Task returning System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String] and not JSON as expected

Tags: c#, async-await, httpclient

I am trying to access the JSON response that the following code should generate:

```
public static async Task<string> GetResponseString(string refreshToken)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.strava.com");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/oauth/token");

        var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "some_id"));
        keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "some_secret"));
        keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", refreshToken));
        keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token"));

        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return result;
    }
```

The expected result looks like this.

```
    {
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "access_token": "a9b723...",
  "expires_at":1568775134,
  "expires_in":20566,
  "refresh_token":"b5c569..."
}
```

When doing this in Postman or Javscript the result is correct, so I guess I am not capable of accessing the task string in a correct manner :-)

Any help pointing me in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Thnx

Comment: You show your code which looks ok but you don't show how you are consuming this code. If it's returning a task and you aren't awaiting the result then you need to do so. The result property of the task will contain the JSON.

Comment: @Charleh I am calling it using 
`var result = collection.GetResponseString("some_token");`

Comment: Right so you need to await the result, the task is async, it runs asynchronously so execution will continue unless you await the result. You can call `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to block the current thread until the async task completes and return the result of the task. `GetResponseString().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, though you might also want to check if the result was successful etc.

Comment: Bear in mind, it's much better to await the result due to potential deadlocks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult though in your case you might be ok, it depends on what's calling the method.

Comment: Thanks you @Charleh
The request just times out now however. I was under the impression that I was already waiting for the result using `var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`  
So the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` should not be necessary ?

Comment: Even if you await it in the async method, if the caller is not async you just get a task back which has to be awaited

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains more than one mistake.

Did you see [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) documentation?
Do you know about [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8)?
Do you know that collection of `KeyValuePair` is `Dictionary`?

Don't use `var` keyword if you're not absolutely sure what are you doing. `var` can hide original problem from you and your question is example how `var` kills your time. I recommend using explicit types where possible.

And yes, as maintained above in comments you must unwrap `string` result from awaitable `Task` with `await`.

```csharp
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private static async Task<string> GetResponseStringAsync(string url, Dictionary<string, string> formData)
{
    using (HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData))
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content))
    {
         response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
         return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
Dictionary<string, string> postData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
postData.Add("client_id", "some_id");
postData.Add("client_secret", "some_secret");
postData.Add("refresh_token", refreshToken);
postData.Add("grant_type", "refresh_token");

try
{
    string result = await GetResponseStringAsync("https://www.strava.com/oauth/token", postData);
    // success here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    // request failed
}
```

And finally, time to say Hello to [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async). :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the code suggestion. I have read the doc about HttpClient, I am however not a native C# programmer, but fluent in front end development. This is just a hobby project for myself.
The `return await response.ReadAsStringAsync();` should be `return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` Right?

Comment: The `string result = await GetResponseStringAsync("https://www.strava.com/oauth/token", postData);` fails as await can only be used within a async method?

Comment: @iAyAy 1) fixed, exactly, thanks! 2) yes, the caller method must be `async`

Comment: @iAyAy what kind of app? Can you show the caller method? Maybe i can help.