# How to capture last trial result in Poly retry policy?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, polly, retry-logic

I am working on extending the `TestMethod` attribute in .NET Core. I am using Polly library for retry logic along with an outer timeout policy.

I want a helper method that can retry invoking the `ITestMethod` until it passes. I don't mind the number of times it'll be retried. But I'll be putting a timeout within which it has to be completed. If the delegate is executed successfully within timeout, it's fine. But if there is a timeout exception, I still want the failed result value (the result of the last iteration) instead of `TimeOutRejectedException` or the default value of the return type.

Below is my extended test method attribute class:

```
public sealed class GuaranteedPassTestMethodAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
    {
        return ExecuteTestTillSuccess(testMethod);
    }

    private TestResult[] ExecuteTestTillSuccess(ITestMethod testMethod)
    {
        var gracefulTestRun =
            TestExecutionHelper.ExecuteTestTillPassAsync(
                () => TestInvokeDelegate(testMethod));

        return gracefulTestRun.Result;
    }

    private Task<TestResult[]> TestInvokeDelegate(ITestMethod testMethod)
    {
        TestResult[] result = null;
        var thread = new Thread(() => result = Invoke(testMethod));
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

Below is my `TestExecutionHelper` that uses Polly:

```
internal static class TestExecutionHelper
{
    private static readonly Func<TestResult[], bool> TestFailurePredicate =
        results => results != null &&
                   results.Length == 1 &&
                   results.First().Outcome != UnitTestOutcome.Passed;

    internal static async Task<TestResult[]> ExecuteTestTillPassAsync(
        Func<Task<TestResult[]>> testInvokeDelegate,
        int delayBetweenExecutionInMs = 3000,
        int timeoutInSeconds = 60 * 10)
    {
        var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<TestResult[]>(timeoutInSeconds);
        var retryPolicy = Policy.HandleResult<TestResult[]>(TestFailurePredicate)
                                .WaitAndRetryAsync(int.MaxValue, x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delayBetweenExecutionInMs));
        var testRunPolicy = timeoutPolicy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy);
        return await testRunPolicy.ExecuteAsync(testInvokeDelegate);
    }
}
```

With this setup, I either get a passed test method execution or `TimeOutRejectedException` for failed tests. I want to capture failed test's `TestResult` even after retries.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this code  `Invoke(testMethod)`? As I can `testMethod.Invoke` does exist but it returns a single `TestResult`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Test case

Let's suppose we have the following test:

```cs
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private static int counter;
    [GuaranteedPassTestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Assert.Fail($"Failed for {++counter}th time");
    }
}
```

I've used a `static` variable (called `counter`) to change the output of each test run.

#### Attribute

I've simplified your attribute's code by making use of the `Task.Run`:

```cs
public sealed class GuaranteedPassTestMethodAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
{
    public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
        => TestExecutionHelper
            .ExecuteTestTillPassAsync(
                async () => await Task.Run(
                    () => testMethod.Invoke(null)))
            .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

I've also changed the `.Result` to `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` for better exception handling.

- If you are not familiar with this pattern please read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult).

#### Strategy

I've introduced an accumulator variable called `Results` where I capture all the test runs' results.

```cs
internal static class TestExecutionHelper
{
    private static readonly List<TestResult> Results = new List<TestResult>();
    private static readonly Func<TestResult, bool> TestFailurePredicate = result =>
    { 
        Results.Add(result);
        return result != null && result.Outcome != UnitTestOutcome.Passed;
    };

    internal static async Task<TestResult[]> ExecuteTestTillPassAsync(
        Func<Task<TestResult>> testInvokeDelegate,
        int delayBetweenExecutionInMs = 3000,
        int timeoutInSeconds = 1 * 10)
    {
        var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<TestResult>(timeoutInSeconds);
        var retryPolicy = Policy.HandleResult(TestFailurePredicate)
            .WaitAndRetryForeverAsync(_ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delayBetweenExecutionInMs));
        var testRunPolicy = timeoutPolicy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy);

        try { await testRunPolicy.ExecuteAsync(testInvokeDelegate); }
        catch (TimeoutRejectedException) { } //Suppress

        return Results.ToArray();
    }
}
```

- I've used here `WaitAndRetryForeverAsync` instead of `WaitAndRetryAsync(int.MaxValue, ...`.
- I've also change the signature of the `testInvokeDelegate` to align to the interface.

#### Output

For my test I've decreased the default value of `timeoutInSeconds` to 10 seconds.

```
 TestMethod1
   Source: UnitTest1.cs line 17

Test has multiple result outcomes
   3 Failed

Results

    1)  TestMethod1
      Duration: 1 sec

      Message: 
        Assert.Fail failed. Failed for 1th time
      Stack Trace: 
        UnitTest1.TestMethod1() line 20
        ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)

    2)  TestMethod1
      Duration: 1 sec

      Message: 
        Assert.Fail failed. Failed for 2th time
      Stack Trace: 
        UnitTest1.TestMethod1() line 20
        ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)

    3)  TestMethod1
      Duration: 1 sec

      Message: 
        Assert.Fail failed. Failed for 3th time
      Stack Trace: 
        UnitTest1.TestMethod1() line 20
        ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)
```

Let's see the timeline for this test run:

- 0 >> 1: `TestMethod1`'s `Delay`
- 1: `Assert.Fail`
- 1 >> 4: Retry's penalty
- 4 >> 5: `TestMethod1`'s `Delay`
- 5: `Assert.Fail`
- 5 >> 8: Retry's penalty
- 8 >> 9: `TestMethod1`'s `Delay`
- 9: `Assert.Fail`
- 9 >> 12: : Retry's penalty
- 10: Timeout kicks in

There is one thing to note here: The Test Duration won't contain the retry's penalty delays:

[image: Test duration]