# cannot convert from system.threding.Tasks .task<byte[]> to byte[]

Tags: c#, image-processing, task

I am new to c# and react. I am using the following method to convert image url to bytes

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

but I am getting an error which says

> cannot convert from `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<byte[]>` to `byte[]`

This is the method:

```
[HttpGet]      
[Route("GetImages")]
public  IHttpActionResult GetImages()
{    
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("corpproxy1.tatasteel.com", 80);
        myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
    //myproxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;    

    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Proxy = myproxy
    };

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var bytes = 
             client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tsl-coil- 
        qlty-monitoring-dev.appspot.com/o/1a60ce3b-eddf-4e72-b2af-b6e99873e926? 
        alt=media&token=61399a02-1009-4bb9-ad89-d1235df900e4");
           
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }    
}
```

How do I correct this error?

Comment: you [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GetByteArrayAsync returns Task, you must wait for the task to complete:

```
var bytes = client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tsl-coil- 
    qlty-monitoring-dev.appspot.com/o/1a60ce3b-eddf-4e72-b2af-b6e99873e926? 
    alt=media&token=61399a02-1009-4bb9-ad89-d1235df900e4").Result
```

OR

```
var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tsl-coil- 
    qlty-monitoring-dev.appspot.com/o/1a60ce3b-eddf-4e72-b2af-b6e99873e926? 
    alt=media&token=61399a02-1009-4bb9-ad89-d1235df900e4")
```

The second way is usually better than the first, it does not block the thread

Comment: I would not encourage the OP to use `.Result`. If (s)he needs to call the async method synchronously then prefer `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult)

Answer (score 2):

`GetByteArrayAsync` is an async method, which returns a Task. You need to await the task to get the return value. In order to await it, the action method has to be async.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetImages")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetImages()
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("corpproxy1.tatasteel.com", 80);
    myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Proxy = myproxy
    };
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tsl-coil- 
             qlty-monitoring-dev.appspot.com/o/1a60ce3b-eddf-4e72-b2af-b6e99873e926? 
             alt=media&token=61399a02-1009-4bb9-ad89-d1235df900e4");
           
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that Now its showing cannot implicitly convert type string to 'System.web.Http.IHttpAction result    for   return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

Comment: public async Task<your return type> GetImages

Comment: @sambit `return Ok(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));`