# C# CS7036 error on SOAP API script saying that it can't find a string I'm passing

Tags: c#, xml, soap, wsdl, compiler-generated

I'm a relatively inexperienced C# developer, mostly using C# for scripting tasks SSIS packages. I'm currently working on a script task for a SOAP API process to update information on external site. Most of the code is autogenerated using a WSDL file from the external site, Visual Studio 2022 and Nuget. I just need to plug in my data and use the autogenerated code, but on a build I am getting a CS7036 error on the 2nd parameter `w3cReconcialationDate` for threading task `updatePaymentStatusAsync`.

I've searched the internet about this error, and most answers say that the correct number of parameters are not being passed. I've triple checked, and I'm passing all the correct parameters in the correct order, so I don't know what's going on.

To debug, I tried commenting out all mention of the parameter `w3ReconciliationDate` and building my code. The same error cropped up on the NEXT string parameter `Action`.

Here is the autogenerated code for the threading task:

```cs
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<XML_Rootobject.updatePaymentStatusResponse> updatePaymentStatusAsync(XML_Rootobject.paymentStatusSearchCriteria criteria, string w3cReconciliationDate, string action, XML_Rootobject.additionalPaymentInformation additionalPaymentInformation, XML_Rootobject.auditLogInfo auditLogInfo)
{
    XML_Rootobject.updatePaymentStatusRequest inValue = new XML_Rootobject.updatePaymentStatusRequest();
    inValue.criteria = criteria;
    inValue.w3cReconciliationDate = w3cReconciliationDate;
    inValue.action = action;
    inValue.additionalPaymentInformation = additionalPaymentInformation;
    inValue.auditLogInfo = auditLogInfo;
    return ((XML_Rootobject.PaymentServiceStronglyTypedType)(this)).updatePaymentStatusAsync(inValue);
}
```

Here is the autogenerated class I am referenced by the previous threading task:

```cs
public partial class updatePaymentStatusRequest
{
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://foobar.com", Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public XML_Rootobject.paymentStatusSearchCriteria criteria;
 
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://foobar.com", Order = 1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string w3cReconciliationDate;
 
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://foobar.com", Order = 2)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string action;
 
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://foobar.com", Order = 3)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public XML_Rootobject.additionalPaymentInformation additionalPaymentInformation;
 
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://foobar.com", Order = 4)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public XML_Rootobject.auditLogInfo auditLogInfo;
 
    public updatePaymentStatusRequest()
    {
    }
 
    public updatePaymentStatusRequest(XML_Rootobject.paymentStatusSearchCriteria criteria, string w3cReconciliationDate, string action, XML_Rootobject.additionalPaymentInformation additionalPaymentInformation, XML_Rootobject.auditLogInfo auditLogInfo)
    {
        this.criteria = criteria;
        this.w3cReconciliationDate = w3cReconciliationDate;
        this.action = action;
        this.additionalPaymentInformation = additionalPaymentInformation;
        this.auditLogInfo = auditLogInfo;
    }
}
```

And this is the code I'm developing to use the class and reference the parameters:

```cs
XML_Rootobject.updatePaymentStatusRequest updPayStReq = new XML_Rootobject.updatePaymentStatusRequest
{
    criteria = ps_criteria, // previously defined object
    w3cReconciliationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"),
    action = "Amend",
    additionalPaymentInformation = addlPaymInfo, // previously defined object
    auditLogInfo = auditLogInf // previously defined object
};

XML_Rootobject.updatePaymentStatusResponse updPayStResp = await HRP_API(updPayStReq);
```

And finally here is the task that is generating the error:

```cs
public static Task<XML_Rootobject.updatePaymentStatusResponse> HRP_API(XML_Rootobject.updatePaymentStatusRequest spType)
{
    ... 
    // Invoke client
    XML_Rootobject.updatedPaymentInformation SP_Resp = new XML_Rootobject.updatedPaymentInformation();
    XML_Rootobject.updatePaymentStatusResponse SubmitResponse = new XML_Rootobject.updatePaymentStatusResponse();
 
    return SubmitResponse = PI_SClient.updatePaymentStatusAsync(spType).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

This is the actual error message:

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'w3cReconciliationDate' of  'ScriptMain.XML_Rootobject.PaymentServiceStronglyTypedTypeClient.updatePaymentStatusAsync(ScriptMain.XML_Rootobject.paymentStatusSearchCriteria, string, string, ScriptMain.XML_Rootobject.additionalPaymentInformation, ScriptMain.XML_Rootobject.auditLogInfo)'  SC_9247ee39793e4fbfb81dbb91b51757ee C:\Users\local_XXXXXX\Temp\3\Vsta\SSIS_SC150\VstalAlxTASoaEKYdRaPNYHaLw\Vsta6SoZShz_z0CC80CnhonTBw\main.cs  230 Active

Sorry for length of this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code you posted is a bit confusing. It looks like you are using the overload of the  updatePaymentStatusAsync method you posted as the first snippet. That is the same overload invoked at the end of the updatePaymentStatusAsync method using a newly created updatePaymentStatusRequest. Have you tried using the method in the snippet instead of creating our own updatePaymentStatusRequest?

Comment: Write code that can be debugged.  Writing code in one line does not make any sense when the optimizer compile will produce the same results 1) var spType = PI_SClient.updatePaymentStatusAsync(spType); 2) var SubmitResponse = spType.GetZAwaiter(); 3) return SubmitResponse;

Comment: @jdweng No one puts `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on different lines, and no one should. No one returns the result of `.GetAwaiter()` either, as it never makes sense.

Comment: @GSerg : It makes sense if you are trying to debug.  What happens when you return a null?  You have to be able to debug code and putting everything on one line makes it impossible to debug and check when you get a null return.

Comment: @jdweng No one debugs the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` which is a way to [call an async function from sync](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17284517/11683). There is nothing to debug. It does not involve nulls either.